# Quiz Program Compiler

Tags: code-golf, compiler

A fun programming exercise is to write a program that quizzes the user from a set list of questions and answers. However, this task goes a level beyond that.

### Your task

- Write a program/func/etc. that takes two lists: A list of questions and a list of answers.
- Output a program that quizzes the user.
- The output program should ask each question on a separate line, which each question with a colon and space at the end like, `What is 2+2:`.
- After the user answers all the questions, output a newline, and then one on each line, questions correct, questions wrong, and percentage calculation (rounded to 2 decimal places) as such (the brackets are user input):

```
What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything: <42>
Am I awesome(Yes/No): <No>
What is 2+2: <4>

Number Correct: 2
Number Wrong: 1
Score: 2 / 3 * 100 = 66.67%
```

### Scoring

- You are scored on the size of your compiler program.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortes code in **bytes** wins!
- **Bonus**: Score *.9 if you implement a flag in your compiler that makes the output program randomize question order.

Comment: If none are correct, or all are wrong, should that line be skipped?

Comment: @Ypnypn no, they should always be there.

Comment: Can I use JS's `prompt` and `alert` for I/O? (As in, prompt each question with the text `<question>: `, then alert each line of the result separately)

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>105</s> 99 bytes

```
{{": "+ol}%.=_:+\,:LX$-X$LX$e2Ld/]"
Number Correct: %d
Number Wrong: %d
Score: %d / %d * 100 = %.2f%%"e%}
```

This defines an anonymous function.

The code is **110 bytes** long and qualifies for the **× 0.9** randomization bonus.

#### Test run

```
$ cat qna.cjam
[
  [
    "42"
    "Yes"
    "4"
  ]

  [
    "What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything"
    "Am I awesome(Yes/No)"
    "What is 2+2"
  ]
]

{zmrz~{": "+ol}%.=_:+\,:LX$-X$LX$e2Ld/]"
Number Correct: %d
Number Wrong: %d
Score: %d / %d * 100 = %.2f%%"e%}

~

$ cjam qna.cjam
What is 2+2: 4
Am I awesome(Yes/No): No
What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything: 42

Number Correct: 2
Number Wrong: 1
Score: 2 / 3 * 100 = 66.67%
```

Comment: Wow, this is the longest CJam answer I have ever seen!

Comment: [Not even close.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51238) :)