# Index of a multidimensional array

Tags: code-golf, math, array

Lower level languages, such as C and C++ actually have no concept of multidimensional arrays. (Other than vectors and dynamic arrays) When you create a multidimensional array with

```
int foo[5][10];
```

This is actually just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). What C really does is create a single contiguous array of *5 * 10* elements. This

```
foo[4][2]
```

is also syntactic sugar. This really refers to the element at

```
4 * 10 + 2
```

or, the 42nd element. In general, the index of element `[a][b]` in array `foo[x][y]` is at

```
a * y + b
```

The same concept applies to 3d arrays. If we have `foo[x][y][z]` and we access element `[a][b][c]` we are really accessing element:

```
a * y * z + b * z + c
```

This concept applies to *n*-dimensional arrays. If we have an array with dimensions `D1, D2, D3 ... Dn` and we access element `S1, S2, S3 ... Sn` the formula is

```
(S1 * D2 * D3 ... * Dn) + (S2 * D3 * D4 ... * Dn) + (S3 * D4 ... * Dn) ... + (Sn-1 * Dn) + Sn
```

## The challenge

You must write a program or function that calculates the index of a multidimensional array according to the formula above. Input will be two arrays. The first array is the dimensions, and the second array is the indices. The length of these two arrays will always be equal and at least 1.

You can safely assume that every number in the arrays will be an non-negative integer. You can also assume that you will not get a `0` in the dimension array, although a `0` *might* be in the indices. You can also assume that indices will not be larger than the dimensions.

## Test IO

```
Dimensions: [5, 10]
Indices: [4, 2]
Output: 42

Dimensions: [10, 10, 4, 62, 7]
Indices: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: 22167

Dimensions: [5, 1, 10]
Indices: [3, 0, 7]
Output: 37

Dimensions: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
Indices: [3, 1, 5, 5, 3, 0, 5, 2, 5, 4]
Output: 33570178
```

Comment: So this is 0-based indexing, correct? Can we use 1-based indexing if that's more natural for our language of choice?

Comment: @AlexA. Yes, that's acceptable.

Comment: Actually, what C 'really does' is create a single contiguous array of five elements of type `int[10]`.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37905/8478)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, but all of the integers in that array are still contiguous. It's just semantics.

Comment: Does someone mind to add the reference output for 1-based indexing? :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## APL, 1 byte

```
⊥
```

Test it on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%20%u2190%20%u22A5%20%u22C4%205%2010%20f%204%202%20%u22C4%2010%2010%204%2062%207%20f%201%202%203%204%205%20%u22C4%205%201%2010%20f%203%200%207%20%u22C4%206%206%206%206%206%206%206%206%206%206%20f%203%201%205%205%203%200%205%202%205%204&run).

Comment: Well, that's it. We have a winner. Everyone else can go home now.

Comment: Why... why does this work? o_O

Comment: @AlexA. Indexing a multidimensional array is essentially mixed base conversion.

Comment: I dont even know anymore

Comment: `W` `O` `W` `!`  `T` `h` `a` `t`  `w` `a` `s`  `G` `O` `O` `D` `!`

Comment: [Link to docs](http://microapl.com/apl_help/ch_020_020_660.htm), for the curious.

Comment: @Dennis You're making it sound easy

Comment: Oh, look, a hole in one while golfing!

Comment: Most of the time I come here for fun. Then there are times when I accidentally receive profound insights

Comment: how do we print that operator `⊥`? I just copied and pasted.

Comment: @kenn In Dyalog APL (including TryAPL), ngn/APL and possibly others, you can press *backtick* followed by *b*.

Comment: @kenn As Dennis said, or, if you have an actual APL keyboard layout installed, [APL]+[b], where [APL]  depends on OS and APL flavor. Btw, "b" is for ***b**ase*, and the symbol looks like the base of a pillar.

Answer (score 12):

## J, 2 bytes

```
#.
```

Where there's an APL, there's a J! Kind of. Takes dimensions as left arg and index as right arg. ["Indexing a multidimensional array is essentially mixed base conversion."](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79609/index-of-a-multidimensional-array#comment195189_79617)

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
(d,a)=>a.reduce((r,i,j)=>r*d[j]+i)
```

Surely `reduce` must be better than `map`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṇ;żḅ@/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmGO8W84biFQC8&input=&args=WzEwLCAxMCwgNCwgNjIsIDdd+WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVd) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmGO8W84biFQC8Kw6ciRw&input=&args=WzUsIDEwXSwgWzEwLCAxMCwgNCwgNjIsIDddLCBbNSwgMSwgMTBdLCBbNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNiwgNl0+WzQsIDJdLCBbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNV0sIFszLCAwLCA3XSwgWzMsIDEsIDUsIDUsIDMsIDAsIDUsIDIsIDUsIDRd).

#### How it works

```
Ṇ;żḅ@/  Main link. Arguments: D (list of dimensions), I (list of indices)

Ṇ       Yield 0, the logical NOT of D.
  ż     Zip D with I.
        If D = [10, 10, 4, 62, 7] and I = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], this yields
        [[10, 1], [10, 2], [4, 3], [62, 4], [7, 5]].
 ;      Concatenate, yielding [0, [10, 1], [10, 2], [4, 3], [62, 4], [7, 5]].
   ḅ@/  Reduce by swapped base conversion to integer.
        [10, 1] in base    0 is    0 × 10 + 1 = 1.
        [10, 2] in base    1 is    1 × 10 + 2 = 12.
        [ 4, 3] in base   12 is   12 ×  4 + 3 = 51.
        [62, 4] in base   51 is   51 × 62 + 4 = 3166.
        [ 7, 5] in base 3166 is 3166 ×  7 + 5 = 22167.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 43 bytes

```
f=lambda x,y:x>[]and y.pop()+x.pop()*f(x,y)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/sYEJFA).

Comment: Not only does Dennis solidly thrash all of us, but he does it in *every. single. language.*

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
e.b=+*ZNYC
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.b%3D%2B*ZNYC&input=[5%2C%2010]%2C%20[4%2C%202]&test_suite_input=[5%2C%2010]%2C%20[4%2C%202]%0A[10%2C%2010%2C%204%2C%2062%2C%203]%2C%20[1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205]%0A[5%2C%201%2C%2010]%2C%20[3%2C%200%2C%207]%0A[6%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206]%2C%20[3%2C%201%2C%205%2C%205%2C%203%2C%200%2C%205%2C%202%2C%205%2C%204]&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.b%3D%2B*ZNYC&input=[5%2C%2010]%2C%20[4%2C%202]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[5%2C%2010]%2C%20[4%2C%202]%0A[10%2C%2010%2C%204%2C%2062%2C%203]%2C%20[1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205]%0A[5%2C%201%2C%2010]%2C%20[3%2C%200%2C%207]%0A[6%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206%2C%206]%2C%20[3%2C%201%2C%205%2C%205%2C%203%2C%200%2C%205%2C%202%2C%205%2C%204]&debug=0)

Using Horner's method to calculate the index.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
4L)1hPYpP*s
```

This uses 0-based indexing, as in the original challenge.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NEwpMWhQWXBQKnM&input=WzEwLCAxMCwgNCwgNjIsIDddClsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1XQ)

#### Explanation

The code explicitly does the required multiplications and additions.

```
4L)    % Take first input array implicitly. Remove its first entry
1h     % Append a 1
PYpP   % Cumulative product from right to left
*      % Take second input array implicitly. Multiply the two arrays element-wise
s      % Sum of resulting array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
PiPZ}N$X]
```

This uses 1-based indexing (now allowed by the challenge), which is the natural choice in MATL.

To compare with the test cases in the challenge, add `1` to each entry in the input index vector, and subtract `1` from the output.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UGlQWn1OJFhd&input=WzEwLCAxMCwgNCwgNjIsIDddClsyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2XQ)

#### Explanation

The code is based on the builtin `X]` function, which converts multidimensional indices to a single, linear index (like Matlab or Octave's `sub2ind` function).

```
P      % Take dimension vector implicitly. Reverse
iP     % Take vector of indices. Reverse
Z}     % Split vector into its elements
N$X]   % Convert indices to linear index (`sub2ind` function). Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
x%y=prod(x)÷cumprod(x)⋅y
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=eCV5PXByb2QoeCnDt2N1bXByb2QoeCnii4V5CgpwcmludGxuKFs1LCAxMF0lWzQsIDJdKQpwcmludGxuKFsxMCwgMTAsIDQsIDYyLCA3XSVbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNV0pCnByaW50bG4oWzUsIDEsIDEwXSVbMywgMCwgN10pCnByaW50bG4oWzYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDYsIDZdJVszLCAxLCA1LCA1LCAzLCAwLCA1LCAyLCA1LCA0XSk&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 85 bytes

```
lambda a,b:sum(b[i]*eval('*'.join(str(n)for n in a[i+1:])or'1')for i in range(len(a)))
```

I'll probably get my butt kicked by the better python golfers out there.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, 69

```
lambda d,i:sum(eval("*".join(map(str,[z,*d])))for z in i if d.pop(0))
```

Test [here](https://repl.it/CO8G)

Comment: Nice answer! Much better than mine.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ I stole the eval method from your solution :)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
a#b=sum$zipWith(*)(0:b)$scanr(*)1a
```

Usage example: `[10,10,4,62,7] # [1,2,3,4,5]` -> `22167`.

How it works:

```
      scanr(*)1a  -- build partial products of the first parameter from the right,
                  -- starting with 1, e.g. [173600,17360,1736,434,7,1]
    (0:b)         -- prepend 0 to second parameter, e.g. [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  zipWith(*)      -- multiply both lists elementwise, e.g. [0,17360,3472,1302,28,5]
sum               -- calculate sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 66 bytes

A quick macro:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define F(d,i) int x d;printf("%d",&x i-(int*)x)
```

Use like:

```
int main(){
    F([5][1][10], [3][0][7]);
}
```

This may be a bit of an abuse of the rules. Creates an array with the given size, than checks to see how far the given indexes offset the pointer. Outputs to STDOUT.

This feels so dirty... But I just love the fact that this is valid.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

*Thanks to @AlexA. for his suggestion, which removed 4 bytes*

```
@(d,i)reshape(1:prod(d),flip(d))(num2cell(flip(i)){:})
```

Input and output are 1-based. To compare with the test cases, add `1` ot each entry in the input and subtract `1` from the output.

This is an anonymous function. To call it, assign it to a variable.

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/NNpIQR).

#### Explanation

This works by actually building the multidimensional array (`reshape(...)`), filled with values `1`, `2`, ... in linear order (`1:prod(d)`), and then indexing with the multidimensional index to get the corrresponding value.

The indexing is done by converting the input multidimensional index `i` into a cell array (`num2cell(...)`) and then to a comma-separated list (`{:}`).

The two `flip` operations are needed to adapt the order of dimensions from C to Octave.

Comment: why does reshape have a second pair of parenthesis isnt that non syntactic?

Comment: @Agawa001 Do you mean a second pair _after_ `reshape`? That's non syntactic in Matlab, but accepted in Octave. It works as an index

Comment: oh Octave!! that must be better and more ergonomic than matlab , tha,ks for enlightenment.

Comment: @Agawa001 It can also lead to [some confusion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29706961#29706961), though

Comment: A tip for anonymous functions in example code: I use `@(...) ...` in the first line of my code, followed by `f = ans;` in the second. This makes the length of the first line equal to the number of bytes to report.

Comment: @bers In that case, why not just skip `f` and call the function using `ans` as its name?

Comment: What a nice idea! Becomes more difficult when you evaluate multiple examples in a row, but should be perfectly valid for a single one.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
#~FromDigits~MixedRadix@#2&
```

An unnamed function which takes the list of indices as the first argument and the list of dimensions second. Based on the same observation as Dennis's APL answer that computing the index is really just a mixed-base conversion.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
0q~z+:b
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MHF-eis6Yg&input=W1sxMCAxMCA0IDYyIDddIFsxIDIgMyA0IDVdXQ)

#### How it works

```
0        e# Push 0 on the stack.
 q       e# Read and push all input, e.g., "[[10 10 4 62 7] [1 2 3 4 5]]".
  ~      e# Eval, pushing [[10 10 4 62 7] [1 2 3 4 5]].
   z     e# Zip, pushing [[10 1] [10 2] [4 3] [62 4] [7 5]].
    +    e# Concatenate, pushing [0 [10 1] [10 2] [4 3] [62 4] [7 5]]
     :b  e# Reduce by base conversion.
         e# [10 1] in base    0 is    0 * 10 + 1 = 1.
         e# [10 2] in base    1 is    1 * 10 + 2 = 12.
         e# [ 4 3] in base   12 is   12 *  4 + 3 = 51.
         e# [62 4] in base   51 is   51 * 62 + 4 = 3166.
         e# [ 7 5] in base 3166 is 3166 *  7 + 5 = 22167.
```

Comment: Give us a chance, Dennis! :D

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 47 bytes

Two equal length solutions:

```
s(a:b)(x:y)=a*product y:s b y
s _ _=[]
(sum.).s
```

Called like: `((sum.).s)[4,2][5,10]`.

Here's an infix version:

```
(a:b)&(x:y)=a*product y:b&y
_ & _=[]
(sum.).(&)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>47</s>/<s>43</s>/31 bytes

`@(d,i)sub2ind(flip(d),num2cell(flip(i+1)){:})-1`

[Test it here](https://ideone.com/E9S01o).

Having said that, as it was asked in a [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79609/index-of-a-multidimensional-array#comment195179_79609), 1-based indexing was said to be OK when this is natural to the language being used. In this case, we can save 4 bytes:

`@(d,i)sub2ind(flip(d),num2cell(flip(i)){:})`

In analogy, I argue that if the objective of the code is to linearly index an array **within that language**, the whole flipping around and accounting for MATLAB/Octave's column major order should not be necessary, either. In that case, my solution becomes

`@(d,i)sub2ind(d,num2cell(i){:})`

[Test that one here](https://ideone.com/2avXAb).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
Fold[Last@#2#+First@#2&,First@#,Rest/@{##}]&
```

(Unicode is U+F3C7, or `\[Transpose]`.) For this, I rewrote the expression as *D*<sub>*n*</sub>(*D*<sub>*n*-1</sub>( ⋯ (*D*<sub>3</sub>(*D*<sub>2</sub>*S*<sub>1</sub> + *S*<sub>2</sub>) + *S*<sub>3</sub>) ⋯ ) + *S*<sub>*n*-1</sub>) + *S*<sub>*n*</sub>. Just `Fold`s the function over both lists.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 13 bytes

```
;pX╗lr`╜tπ`M*
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O3BY4pWXbHJg4pWcdM-AYE0q&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdClsxMCwgMTAsIDQsIDYyLCA3XQ)

This program takes the list of indices as the first input and the list of dimensions as the second input.

Explanation:

```
;pX╗lr`╜tπ`M*
;pX╗            push dims[1:] to reg0
    lr`   `M    map: for n in range(len(dims)):
       ╜tπ        push product of last n values in reg0
            *   dot product of indices and map result
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 76 bytes

```
(λ(l i(s 0))(if(null? i)s(f(cdr l)(cdr i)(+ s(*(car i)(apply *(cdr l)))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ (ll il (sum 0))
    (if (null? il)
        sum
        (f (rest ll)
           (rest il)
           (+ sum
              (* (first il)
                 (apply * (rest ll))))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f '(5 10) '(4 2))
(f '(10 10 4 62 7) '(1 2 3 4 5))
(f '(5 1 10) '(3 0 7))
```

Output:

```
42
22167
37
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <strike>119</strike> 79 bytes

```js
x=(d,i)=>{a=0;for(m in d){m*=1;a+=i[m];if(m!=i.length-1){a*=d[m+1];}}return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjJDoMgFEDRX3ndgaKRDnZBXn@EsCCCloahQduYGL@dDoubnNyHfut5yO65NDEZW8qKxDBH8bZp7MSYMgngIhi6hQq50DU6GZRwIwkHdK23cVruDaebrtDIUHMl9j3b5ZUjaLGXIcU5edv6NJGVSN4x@HVm0B8ZXBWTnMFXp/@7KEpF@QA)

Comment: Nice answer! You can save at least 20 bytes by using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and leaving out the `var`.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 73 bytes

```
d=>i=>{int n=d.Length,x=0,y=1;for(;n>0;){x+=y*i[--n];y*=d[n];}return x;};
```

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

namespace IndexOfAMultidimensionalArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int[],Func<int[],int>>f= d=>i=>{int n=d.Length,x=0,y=1;for(;n>0;){x+=y*i[--n];y*=d[n];}return x;};
            
            int[] dimensions, indices;
            dimensions =new int[]{5, 10};
            indices=new int[]{4,2};
            Console.WriteLine(f(dimensions)(indices));      //42

            dimensions=new int[]{10, 10, 4, 62, 7};
            indices=new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            Console.WriteLine(f(dimensions)(indices));      //22167
            
            dimensions=new int[]{5, 1, 10};
            indices=new int[]{3, 0, 7};
            Console.WriteLine(f(dimensions)(indices));      //37

            dimensions=new int[]{6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6};
            indices=new int[]{3, 1, 5, 5, 3, 0, 5, 2, 5, 4};
            Console.WriteLine(f(dimensions)(indices));      //33570178
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 39 bytes

```
->\d,\i{sum i.map:{[×] $_,|d[++$ ..*]}}
```

A rather naive golf here, just squished a anonymous sub.

Perl 6 has an anonymous state variable `$` which is useful for creating a counter in a loop (eg, using post-increment `$++` or pre-increment `++$`).
I pre-increment this state variable to increment the starting index of the dimension array slice inside a map.

Here's a ungolfed function that creates the sub-lists

```
sub md-index(@dim, @idx) {
    @idx.map(-> $i { $i, |@dim[++$ .. *] })
}
say md-index([10, 10, 4, 62, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
# OUTPUT: ((1 10 4 62 7) (2 4 62 7) (3 62 7) (4 7) (5))
```

Then it's just a matter of reducing the sub-lists with the multiplication  (`×`) operator, and `sum`ing the results.

```
sub md-index(@dim, @idx) {
    @idx.map(-> $i { [×] $i, |@dim[++$ .. *] }).sum
}
say md-index([10, 10, 4, 62, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
# OUTPUT: 22167
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 71 bytes

```
sub{$s+=$_[1][-$_]*($p*=$_[0][1-$_])for($p=$_[0][$s=0]=1)..@{$_[0]};$s}
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub {
    my $s = 0;
    my $p = 1;

    $_[0]->[0] = 1;
    for (1 .. @{$_[1]}) {
        $p *= $_[0]->[1 - $_];
        $s += $_[1]->[-$_] * $p;
    }

    return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++17, <s>133</s> 115 bytes

-18 bytes for using `auto...`

```c++
template<int d,int ...D>struct M{int f(int s){return s;}int f(int s,auto...S){return(s*...*D)+M<D...>().f(S...);}};
```

Ungolfed:

```c++
template <int d,int ...D> //extract first dimension
struct M{
 int f(int s){return s;} //base case for Sn
 int f(int s, auto... S) { //extract first index 
  return (s*...*D)+M<D...>().f(S...); 
  //S_i * D_(i+1) * D(i+2) * ... + recursive without first dimension and first index
 }
};
```

Usage:

```c++
M<5,10>().f(4,2)
M<10,10,4,62,7>().f(1,2,3,4,5)
```

### Alternative, only functions, 116 bytes

```c++
#define R return
#define A auto
A f(A d){R[](A s){R s;};}A f(A d,A...D){R[=](A s,A...S){R(s*...*D)+f(D...)(S...);};}
```

Ungolfed:

```c++
auto f(auto d){
  return [](auto s){
   return s;
  };
}
auto f(auto d, auto...D){
  return [=](auto s, auto...S){
    return (s*...*D)+f(D...)(S...);
  };
}
```

Usage:

```c++
f(5,10)(4,2)
f(10,10,10)(4,3,2)
f(10,10,4,62,7)(1,2,3,4,5)
```