# Where's the 0xBEEF?

Tags: code-golf, binary, matrix

This challenge was inspired by [this Wendy's commercial](https://youtu.be/eANcbFSPHyA) from 1984.

[image: Where's the beef?]

*<sub>Illustration by T S Rogers</sub>*

Your task is to find a hexadecimal 0xBEEF on a binary bun.

The 'beef' consists of the following pattern:

```
1 0 1 1  (0xB)
1 1 1 0  (0xE)
1 1 1 0  (0xE)
1 1 1 1  (0xF)
```

And the 'bun' consists of a 12x12 binary matrix, such as:

```
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

#### Input

Your program or function will take the binary matrix as input. The matrix format is very flexible, but it must be clearly described in your answer.

For instance:

- a single binary string, with or without separators between the rows:

  `"111001111110 110100100000..."`

  or:

  `"111001111110110100100000..."`
- an array of binary strings:

  `["111001111110", "110100100000", ...]`
- an array of numbers (each number describing a row once converted back to binary and left-padded with zeros):

  `[3710, 3360, ...]`

#### Output

The coordinates `(X, Y)` of the 'beef', `(0, 0)` being the top left corner of the bun.

Alternatively, you may use 1-based coordinates (but not a mix of both formats, like 0-based for X and 1-based for Y).

For the above example, the expected answer is `(3, 4)` (0-based) or `(4, 5)` (1-based):

```
   00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 
00  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
01  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
02  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
03  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
04  1  0  0 [1  0  1  1] 0  0  1  1  1
05  1  1  1 [1  1  1  0] 0  0  0  1  0
06  1  1  0 [1  1  1  0] 0  0  0  0  1
07  1  0  0 [1  1  1  1] 0  0  0  0  1
08  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
09  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
10  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1
11  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Again, any reasonable format would work as long as it is specified in your answer. Please also mention if you're using 0-based or 1-based coordinates.

#### Rules

- You can safely assume that there is always exactly one 'beef' on the bun. Your code is not required to support cases with more than one beef or no beef at all.
- The beef pattern will always appear as described. It will never be rotated or mirrored in any way.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

#### Test cases

In the following test cases, each row of the matrix is expressed as its decimal representation.

```
Input : [ 3710, 3360, 1149, 2340, 2407, 4034, 3521, 2529, 2527, 3999, 2135, 3267 ]
Output: [ 3, 4 ]

Input : [ 1222, 3107, 1508, 3997, 1906, 379, 2874, 2926, 1480, 1487, 3565, 633 ]
Output: [ 3, 7 ]

Input : [ 2796, 206, 148, 763, 429, 1274, 2170, 2495, 42, 1646, 363, 1145 ]
Output: [ 6, 4 ]

Input : [ 3486, 3502, 1882, 1886, 2003, 1442, 2383, 2808, 1416, 1923, 2613, 519 ]
Output: [ 1, 1 ]

Input : [ 3661, 2382, 2208, 1583, 1865, 3969, 2864, 3074, 475, 2382, 1838, 127 ]
Output: [ 8, 8 ]

Input : [ 361, 1275, 3304, 2878, 3733, 3833, 3971, 3405, 2886, 448, 3101, 22 ]
Output: [ 0, 3 ]

Input : [ 3674, 2852, 1571, 3582, 1402, 3331, 1741, 2678, 2076, 2685, 734, 261 ]
Output: [ 7, 7 ]
```

Comment: Is using 1-based indices allowed (where the top left is `(1,1)`)?

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, if it's the same format for both X and Y (question updated accordingly).

Comment: Bonus points if we also output wether the 0xBEEF is 0xDEAD? :P

Comment: This challenge is really random and kinda silly. But it's actually a pretty great challenge still. +1

Comment: Can I output `y`, `x` (i.e. reverse order)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that's OK.

Comment: Can input be a "binary" matrix containing `1`, `-1` instead of `1`, `0`?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, I expect either numbers or some "standard binary" representation made of zeros and ones.

Comment: Can I return the output as a string, e.g., `'34'`?

Comment: @Dennis - Yes. (Provided that it means `(3, 4)` and not the 34th position.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is the "bun" always exactly 12x12?

Comment: @JDL Yes it is.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: it is not really random : http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DEADBEEF.html . see also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values

Comment: Mmm I want someone to `0xFEED` me some `0xDEAD 0xBEEF`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṡ€4ḄZw€“¿ÇÇÐ‘ĖUṀ
```

Input is in form of a Boolean matrix, output is the 1-based index pair **(Y, X)**.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmh4oKsNOG4hFp34oKs4oCcwr_Dh8OHw5DigJjEllXhuYA&input=&args=WzEsMSwxLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwwXSwgWzEsMSwwLDEsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwwXSwgWzAsMSwwLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwxXSwgWzEsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDEsMCwwXSwgWzEsMCwwLDEsMCwxLDEsMCwwLDEsMSwxXSwgWzEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDAsMCwwLDAsMSwwXSwgWzEsMSwwLDEsMSwxLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwxXSwgWzEsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwxXSwgWzEsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDAsMSwxLDEsMSwxXSwgWzEsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMSwxLDEsMSwxXSwgWzEsMCwwLDAsMCwxLDAsMSwwLDEsMSwxXSwgWzEsMSwwLDAsMSwxLDAsMCwwLDAsMSwxXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmh4oKsNOG4hFp34oKs4oCcwr_Dh8OHw5DigJjEllXhuYAKfDQwOTZC4biK4oKsw4fCteKCrEc&input=&args=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).

#### How it works

```
ṡ€4ḄZw€“¿ÇÇÐ‘ĖUṀ  Main link. Argument: M (2D array of Booleans)

ṡ€4               Split each row into 9 chunks of length 4.
   Ḅ              Convert these chunks from base 2 to integer.
    Z             Zip/transpose. This places the columns of generated integers
                  into the rows of the matrix to comb through them.
       “¿ÇÇÐ‘     Push the array of code points (in Jelly's code page) of these
                  characters, i.e., 0xB, 0xE, 0xE, and 0xF.
     w€           Window-index each; in each row, find the index of the contiguous
                  subarray [0xB, 0xE, 0xE, 0xF] (0 if not found).
                  Since the matrix contains on one BEEF, this will yield an array
                  of zeroes, with a single non-zero Y at index X.
             Ė    Enumerate; prefix each integer with its index.
              U   Upend; reverse the pairs to brings the zeroes to the beginning.
               Ṁ  Take the maximum. This yields the only element with positive
                  first coordinate, i.e., the pair [Y, X].
```

Comment: I don't get it... how can you code something that is not human readable??

Comment: Jelly is by far easier to write than to read. :P

Comment: @l3n you seem to imply that Dennis is a human. While it is a possibility, given the kind of tricks that routinely pulls out, I wouldn't discount other ... let's say, more cyberpunk alternatives ;-)

Comment: You could output (x,y) with `ṡ4Z€Ḅw€“Ð¬Ðµ‘ĖUṀ`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice. There's also `ṡ€4ḄZjw“¿ÇÇÐ‘’d24` with 0-based indexing, but it is, unfortunately, one byte longer.

Comment: This is 16 _characters_, but 35 _bytes_ (in UTF-8).

Comment: @Useless The *bytes* link in the header points to Jelly's code page, which encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a single byte.

Comment: Very ingenious!

Answer (score 42):

### vim, <s>126</s> <s>80</s> <s>77</s> 76

```
/\v1011\_.{9}(1110\_.{9}){2}1111<cr>:exe'norm Go'.join(getpos('.'))<cr>xxdawhPXXd{
```

Expects input in the form

```
111001111110
110100100000
010001111101
100100100100
100101100111
111111000010
110111000001
100111100001
100111011111
111110011111
100001010111
110011000011
```

And outputs (with 1-based indices) as

```
4 5
```

```
/                      regex search for...
\v                     enable "very magic" mode (less escaping)
1011\_.{9}             find the first line ("B"), followed by 8 chars + 1 \n
(1110\_.{9}){2}        find the second and third lines ("EE")
1111<cr>               find the fourth line ("F")
:exe'norm Go'.         insert at the beginning of the file...
join(getpos('.'))<cr>  the current position of the cursor
xxdawhPXX              do some finagling to put the numbers in the right order
d{                     delete the input
```

Thanks to [Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%c3%b6rg-h%c3%bclsermann) for indirectly saving 46 bytes by making me realize my regex was super dumb, and to [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) for 3 more bytes.

Comment: A couple tips: 1) `Yp` is better than `yyp` (even though I know you object to `Y` :P) 2) the whitespace in `exec 'norm Go'` is unnecessary. And 3) `kd{` is shorter than `kdgg`. (Haven't tested that though)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Oh, I always forget about `Y` because I have it rebound in my vimrc. :P In fact, the `kdgg` was equivalent to just `d{`, which, surprisingly, does not delete the current line.

Comment: Oh interesting. How convenient!

Comment: I'm always confused when things such as `{` turn out to be a character movement; so I have do something like `{d''` instead to delete whole lines.

Comment: @Neil You could do `dV{` instead

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I learned vi in the old days, so I'm not used to all these new options such as visual mode!

Comment: While you actually encoded B your comment says D.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Whoops, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You could use echo instead of printing into the buffer, I don't think there's anything preventing this in the challenge. That would shave off around 10 bytes.

Answer (score 22):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>63</s> <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
s=>[(i=s.search(/1011.{9}(1110.{9}){2}1111/))%13,i/13|0]
```

Takes input as a 155-character space-delimited string of 12 12-digit binary strings, returns zero-indexed values. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @JörgHülsermann. Saved 4 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: Could you possibly use `s.search(r)` instead of `r.exec(s).index`?

Comment: @ETHproductions Of course I could. I must have been half asleep yesterday...

Comment: For me, using nodejs to execute, it is not working unless i change `s=>[` to  `(s,i)=>[`, because you need to define i somewhere :/

Comment: @Mijago Odd, it worked in Node 4 when I tried it (I normally use the Spidermonkey JS shell). Mind you a typo had crept into the code so some good came out of it!

Comment: I think this fails for 000010110010110011100011100011100011100011110011110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @Taemyr Actually it works for your case but if fails if I change the first `1` to a `0`, so I fixed my code (fortunately that didn't cost me any bytes).

Comment: @Neil I am happy my last comment on the Retina solution got in before your fix.

Comment: @Neil It was my "use static"; i use everywhere which forces me to define every variable. Mystery solved!

Answer (score 14):

## C, <s>146</s> <s>177</s> <s>173</s> 163 bytes

Thanks to [Numberknot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97212/53667) for fixing the code (shifting the lower three rows).

Saving 4 bytes by replacing `>>=1` with `/=2` in 4 places.
Saving 10 more bytes by letting `x` and `y` be global and default `int` thanks to [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```c
#define T(i,n)(A[y+i]&15)==n
x,y;b(int A[12]){for(x=9;x--;){for(y=0;++y<9;A[y]/=2)if(T(0,11)&&T(1,14)&&T(2,14)&&T(3,15))return(x<<4)+y;A[9]/=2;A[10]/=2;A[11]/=2;}}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
int b(int A[12]) {
 for (int x=8; x>=0; --x) {
  for (int y=0; y<9; ++y) {
   if ((A[y]&15)==11 && (A[y+1]&15)==14 && (A[y+2]&15)==14 && (A[y+3]&15)==15) { 
    return (x<<4) + y; 
   }
   A[y]/=2;
  }
  A[9]/=2; A[10]/=2; A[11]/=2;
 }
}
```

Returns x,y (0-based) in the high and low nibble of a byte.

Usage:

```c
int temp=b(array_to_solve);
int x=temp>>4;
int y=temp&15;
printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
```

Comment: you can change your define to `#define T(i,n)if((A[y+i]&15)==n)` and the if section to `T(0,11)T(1,14)T(2,14)T(3,15)return` to save 6 bytes. Also change the function signature to `int b(int*A)` to 4 more bytes saved.

Comment: [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcyxCsMgEMbxvU8RKIQ7NDSXpoMYh7xDtuDSVIuLBUlBKXl2a1My3e@G/7c0z2XJ@fww1nlTTeC4RxjnxJyu6YZK@VPkSd7B@bUaZ@o0fuwrQFRCxqaR/y@pVjKWBiFLqi@qQ2dhgpYTYV1PQJz6Hd2BKy/rGMz6Dh7iMPTIUonFLy6X2gO0Y9ty/gI)

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
Eq[ODDH]B~EqZ+16=&fhq
```

Input is a binary matrix, with `;` as row separator. Output is 1-based in reverse order: `Y X`.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RXFbT0RESF1CfkVxWisxNj0mZmhx&input=WzEgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAwOyAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMDsgMCAxIDAgMCAwIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAwIDE7IDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwOyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDEgMTsgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAwIDAgMCAxIDA7IDEgMSAwIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAxOyAxIDAgMCAxIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMTsgMSAwIDAgMSAxIDEgMCAxIDEgMSAxIDE7IDEgMSAxIDEgMSAwIDAgMSAxIDEgMSAxOyAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMSAwIDEgMCAxIDEgMTsgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDEgMCAwIDAgMCAxIDFd) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YEIKRXFbT0RESF1CfkVxWisxNj0mZmhxCkRU&input=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) with decimal input format.

#### Explanation

The pattern is detected using 2D convolution. For this,

- The matrix and the pattern need to be in bipolar form, that is, `1, -1` instead of `1, 0`. Since the pattern has size 4×4, its occurrence is detected by an entry equal to `16` in the convolution output.
- The convolution kernel needs to be defined as the sought pattern reversed in both dimensions.

Also, since the convolution introduces an offset in the detected indices, this needs to be corrected for in the output.

```
Eq      % Implicitly input binary matrix. Convert to bipolar form (0 becomes -1)
[ODDH]  % Push array [0 8 8 2]
B       % Convert to binary. Each number gives a row
~Eq     % Negate and convert to bipolar. Gives [1 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1; 0 1 1 1; 1 1 0 1]
        % This is the "BEEF" pattern reversed in the two dimensions. Reversal is
        % needed because a convolution will be used to detect that patter
Z+      % 2D convolution, keeping original size
16=&f   % Find row and column indices of 16 in the above matrix
h       % Concatenate horizontally
q       % Subtract 1. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
BlockMap[Fold[#+##&,Join@@#]==48879&,#,{4,4},1]~Position~True&
```

Returns all positions of the BEEF matrix, 1-indexed. The input must be a matrix of binary digits. The x and y in the output are switched, though.

Comment: No worries about `x` and `y` being switched.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 87 Bytes

binary string as input without separators, returns zero-indexed values.

```
preg_match("#1011(.{8}1110){2}.{8}1111#",$argv[1],$c,256);echo($s=$c[0][1])%12,$s/12^0;
```

array of numbers as input 128 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET[a]as$a)$b.=sprintf("%012b",$a);preg_match("#1011(.{8}1110){2}.{8}1111#",$b,$c,256);echo($s=$c[0][1])%12,$s/12^0;
```

14 Bytes saved by [@Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) Thank You

Comment: Use `,` instead of `.` in the `echo` and you can remove the parentheses. (-4)

Comment: In the comments, Arnauld allows output without a delimiter. (-4)

Comment: Use flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`: append `,256` to the `preg_match` parameters, remove `^(.*)` from the regex, `$c[0][1]` instead of `strlen($c[1])` (-6)

Comment: @Titus nice and done

Answer (score 7):

### [Slip](https://github.com/Sp3000/Slip/wiki), 28 bytes

27 bytes of code, +1 for `p` option.

```
(?|1011)(\(?|1110)){2}\1111
```

Requires input as a multiline rectangle of 1's and 0's without spaces. [Try it here](https://slip-online.herokuapp.com/?code=%28%3F%7C1011%29%28%5C%28%3F%7C1110%29%29%7B2%7D%5C1111&input=101011101100%0A000011001110%0A000010010100%0A001011111011%0A000110101101%0A010011111010%0A100001111010%0A100110111111%0A000000101010%0A011001101110%0A000101101011%0A010001111001&config=p) (with third testcase as input).

#### Explanation

Slip is a language from the [2-D Pattern Matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47311/16766) challenge. Sp3000 could say a lot more about it than I can, but basically it's an extended form of regex with some directional commands that let you match in two dimensions. The above code uses the eponymous "slip" command `\`, which doesn't change the match pointer's direction but moves it sideways by one character. It also uses "stationary group" `(?|...)`, which matches something and then resets the pointer to its previous location.

The code breaks down as follows:

```
(?|1011)                     Match 1011; reset pointer to beginning of match
        (         ){2}       Do the following twice:
         \                     Slip (moves pointer down one row)
          (?|1110)             Match 1110; reset pointer to beginning of match
                      \1111  Slip and match 1111
```

This matches the `0xBEEF` square. The `p` option outputs the coordinates of the match, 0-indexed.

Comment: Nice :) Weirdly, for block patterns sometimes it's golfier to just walk around in a spiral: `1011>001>1(11>){3}1>1`

Comment: @Sp3000 Ha! Spiral was the shortest method in SnakeEx, but I didn't think of trying it in Slip. Really nice trick with the `1(11>){3}`.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7,<del>182</del> 177 bytes

[I ported Karl Napf **C** answer to **JAVA**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97196/58766) And Thanks to [Karl Napf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97196/58766) for saving 5 bytes by reminding me Bit magic.(Btw i came up with this idea too but @KarlNapf return part idea was yours not mine).Sorry if i displeased you.

(0-based)

```java
int f(int[]a){int x=9,y,z=0;for(;x-->0;){for(y=0;y<9;a[y++]/=2) if((a[y]&15)==11&(a[y+1]&15)==14&(a[y+2]&15)==14&(a[y+3]&15)==15)z=(x<<4)+y;a[y]/=2;a[10]/=2;a[11]/=2;}return z;}
```

## Ungolfed

```java
class Beef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = f(new int[] { 1222, 3107, 1508, 3997, 1906, 379, 2874, 2926, 1480, 1487, 3565, 633 });
        System.out.println(x >> 4);
        System.out.println(x & 15);
    }

    static int f(int[] a) {
        int x = 9,
            y,
            z = 0;

        for (; x-- > 0; ) {
            for (y = 0; y < 9; a[y++] /= 2)
                if ((a[y] & 15) == 11 
                  & (a[y + 1] & 15) == 14
                  & (a[y + 2] & 15) == 14 
                  & (a[y + 3] & 15) == 15)
                    z = (x << 4) + y;

            a[y] /= 2;
            a[10] /= 2;
            a[11] /= 2;
        }
        return z;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are those four spaces there between `a[y++]>>=1)` and `if((a[y]&15)==`. Btw, I count 182 bytes instead of 183? :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed .

Comment: Everything alright ;-)

Comment: You can still remove the space between `...a[y++]/=2)` and `if((a[y]&15)==...`.

Answer (score 5):

## Scala, 90 bytes

```
("1011.{8}(1110.{8}){2}1111".r.findAllMatchIn(_:String).next.start)andThen(i=>(i/12,i%12))
```

Explanation:

```
(
  "1011.{8}(1110.{8}){2}1111" //The regex we're using to find the beef
  .r                          //as a regex object
  .findAllMatchIn(_:String)   //find all the matches in the argument thats going to be passed here
  .next                       //get the first one
  .start                      //get its start index
)                             //this is a (String -> Int) function
andThen                       //
(i=>                          //with the found index
  (i/12,i%12)                 //convert it to 2d values
)
```

`(a -> b) andThen (b -> c)` results in a `(a -> c)` function, it's like the reverse of compose, but requires fewer type annotations in scala. In this case, it takes a string of the binary digits as input and returns a tuple of zero-based indices.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>98</s> <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```python
lambda x:'%x'%(`[''.join('%x'%int(s[i:i+4],2)for s in x)for i in range(9)]`.find('beef')+15)
```

Input is a list of strings, output is the string **XY** (1-based indices).

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/cNWRuY).

Comment: Might this mistakenly find a "beef" across the boundary where two lines are concatenated?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I'll roll the edit back until I can test it properly.

Comment: That's what happens when you use a toroidal bun.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 51 bytes

Uses 0-based indices. Expects input as a string of `1`s and `0`s and outputs space separated co-ordinates.

Thanks to @[wullxz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61114/wullxz) and @[GabrielBenamy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60884/gabriel-benamy) for helping me save 9 bytes, and to @[Taemyr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16596/taemyr)'s comment on my Retina answer for pointing out an issue!

```perl
/1011.{9}(1110.{9}){2}1111/;say"@-"%13,$","@-"/13|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVRBTsNADLznFVYEAqSm8VD1gLjwAR7BgQMSaivKBZV@nSUbz3iTaKuu47Uznpnk9P71uS9lhAPby9P1HoDXzcPl8TrtMT6f3376l6G/xW5z02/qdsTu10upRx3z5Tb9auT1svk/ErC4HSsC1hlr69loEAFrlGIQ/YwlDKIW7ObOEnSugNjcicnitOBkN68ZYZhqonHcsYQ8A3VwwdktmreAcFheW3tOhI6A554WeJ3dnERFBuIQFqfUDcmuk4MWiKm5RvRUbJnL4RwkZIEtR5UknpMmgEWgDOUnvdFSaouQnEdUefKWyscxDWtyVD3RiejmKvEGzknzIcUT0HlZ2i1c1Qxjup3SS@L1c6R1ikWqJ78lo2t9ZMtA14wU9EJqw9Lha6A00mJsJEEC6ssRaOXUHt4l6HSv3samQTMs0tfNVWgymKdFnGKRLGtSxaTtE6DHN/MR3V33dzx9fxwP5zK87rfTp8fLcPgH)

Comment: You can save 3 characters by combining the regex for the binary EE: `(.{8}1110){2}` instead of `.{8}1110.{8}1110`

Comment: You can also save another 3 bytes by changing `length$\`` into `$-[0]`

Comment: @wullxz Of course! I tried `\1` but had no luck, didn't think to try `{2}`! Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielBenamy Amazing, thank you very much! Updated!

Comment: @GabrielBenamy What does `$-[0]` do?

Comment: @User112638726 "`$-[0]` is the offset of the start of the last successful match. `$-[n]` is the offset of the start of the substring matched by n-th subpattern, or `undef` if the subpattern did not match." from: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html (look for `@-`)

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks! I'll have a look

Answer (score 5):

### Retina, 47 bytes

I'd like to preface this with an apology. I think this is probably terrible and a bad example of how to use the language, but since I used a Regex for my Perl answer, I thought I'd try Retina. I'm not very good. :( The [snippets on github](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki) helped me greatly though!

Thanks to @[wullzx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61114/wullxz) for his comment on my Perl answer for -3 bytes and to @[Taemyr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16596/taemyr) for pointing out an issue with my method!

Expects input as a space-separated binary string and outputs co-ordinates space separated.

```
(.{13})*(.)*1011(.{9}1110){2}.{9}1111.*
$#2 $#1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KC57MTN9KSooLikqMTAxMSguezl9MTExMCl7Mn0uezl9MTExMS4qCiQjMiAkIzE&input=MTExMDAxMTExMTEwIDExMDEwMDEwMDAwMCAwMTAwMDExMTExMDEgMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAwIDEwMDEwMTEwMDExMSAxMTExMTEwMDAwMTAgMTEwMTExMDAwMDAxIDEwMDExMTEwMDAwMSAxMDAxMTEwMTExMTEgMTExMTEwMDExMTExIDEwMDAwMTAxMDExMSAxMTAwMTEwMDAwMTE)

[Verify all tests at once.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShgKC57MTN9KSooLikqMTAxMSguezl9MTExMCl7Mn0uezl9MTExMS4qCiQjMiAkIzE&input=MTExMDAxMTExMTEwIDExMDEwMDEwMDAwMCAwMTAwMDExMTExMDEgMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAwIDEwMDEwMTEwMDExMSAxMTExMTEwMDAwMTAgMTEwMTExMDAwMDAxIDEwMDExMTEwMDAwMSAxMDAxMTEwMTExMTEgMTExMTEwMDExMTExIDEwMDAwMTAxMDExMSAxMTAwMTEwMDAwMTEKMDEwMDExMDAwMTEwIDExMDAwMDEwMDAxMSAwMTAxMTExMDAxMDAgMTExMTEwMDExMTAxIDAxMTEwMTExMDAxMCAwMDAxMDExMTEwMTEgMTAxMTAwMTExMDEwIDEwMTEwMTEwMTExMCAwMTAxMTEwMDEwMDAgMDEwMTExMDAxMTExIDExMDExMTEwMTEwMSAwMDEwMDExMTEwMDEKMTAxMDExMTAxMTAwIDAwMDAxMTAwMTExMCAwMDAwMTAwMTAxMDAgMDAxMDExMTExMDExIDAwMDExMDEwMTEwMSAwMTAwMTExMTEwMTAgMTAwMDAxMTExMDEwIDEwMDExMDExMTExMSAwMDAwMDAxMDEwMTAgMDExMDAxMTAxMTEwIDAwMDEwMTEwMTAxMSAwMTAwMDExMTEwMDEKMTEwMTEwMDExMTEwIDExMDExMDEwMTExMCAwMTExMDEwMTEwMTAgMDExMTAxMDExMTEwIDAxMTExMTAxMDAxMSAwMTAxMTAxMDAwMTAgMTAwMTAxMDAxMTExIDEwMTAxMTExMTAwMCAwMTAxMTAwMDEwMDAgMDExMTEwMDAwMDExIDEwMTAwMDExMDEwMSAwMDEwMDAwMDAxMTEKMTExMDAxMDAxMTAxIDEwMDEwMTAwMTExMCAxMDAwMTAxMDAwMDAgMDExMDAwMTAxMTExIDAxMTEwMTAwMTAwMSAxMTExMTAwMDAwMDEgMTAxMTAwMTEwMDAwIDExMDAwMDAwMDAxMCAwMDAxMTEwMTEwMTEgMTAwMTAxMDAxMTEwIDAxMTEwMDEwMTExMCAwMDAwMDExMTExMTEKMDAwMTAxMTAxMDAxIDAxMDAxMTExMTAxMSAxMTAwMTExMDEwMDAgMTAxMTAwMTExMTEwIDExMTAxMDAxMDEwMSAxMTEwMTExMTEwMDEgMTExMTEwMDAwMDExIDExMDEwMTAwMTEwMSAxMDExMDEwMDAxMTAgMDAwMTExMDAwMDAwIDExMDAwMDAxMTEwMSAwMDAwMDAwMTAxMTAKMTExMDAxMDExMDEwIDEwMTEwMDEwMDEwMCAwMTEwMDAxMDAwMTEgMTEwMTExMTExMTEwIDAxMDEwMTExMTAxMCAxMTAxMDAwMDAwMTEgMDExMDExMDAxMTAxIDEwMTAwMTExMDExMCAxMDAwMDAwMTExMDAgMTAxMDAxMTExMTAxIDAwMTAxMTAxMTExMCAwMDAxMDAwMDAxMDE)

Comment: Fails for '000010110010110011100011100011100011100011110011110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'  Your (.)* needs to be (.){0,8}

Comment: Is this countered by `You can safely assume that there is always exactly one 'beef' on the bun. Your code is not required to support cases with more than one beef or no beef at all.`? It can be resolved with ungreedy modifiers if necessary though `(.{12})*?(.)*?`.

Comment: Look again, there is only one beef in that input - and it's not at the point where your program indicates.  The problem would not be resolved by using eager modifers, since I can switch the fake beef with the real beef.  the problem is that your regex matches a "beef" that starts less than 4 bits from the end of a matrix row.

Comment: You could also resolve this by changing the {8}'s to {9} and asking for the lines in the input to be space seperated, for a zero byte cost fix.

Comment: @Taemyr Ahhh! I see! I misunderstood your point... You are indeed correct. My Perl solution potentially falls foul of this as well. Will get that changed ASAP. Thank you for your comments and suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

## J, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
[:($#:I.@,)48879=4 4#.@,;._3]
```

The input is formatted as a 2d array of binary values, and the output is the zero-based coordinates as an array `[y, x]`.

The flattening and base conversion to find the index is something I learned from this [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79609/index-of-a-multidimensional-array#comment195189_79617) by Dennis.

### Usage

```
   f =: [:($#:I.@,)48879=4 4#.@,;._3]
   ] m =: _12 ]\ 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
   f m
4 3
   f (#:~2#~#) 3710 3360 1149 2340 2407 4034 3521 2529 2527 3999 2135 3267
4 3
   f (#:~2#~#) 1222 3107 1508 3997 1906 379 2874 2926 1480 1487 3565 633
7 3
   f (#:~2#~#) 2796 206 148 763 429 1274 2170 2495 42 1646 363 1145
4 6
   f (#:~2#~#) 3486 3502 1882 1886 2003 1442 2383 2808 1416 1923 2613 519
1 1
   f (#:~2#~#) 3661 2382 2208 1583 1865 3969 2864 3074 475 2382 1838 127
8 8
   f (#:~2#~#) 361 1275 3304 2878 3733 3833 3971 3405 2886 448 3101 22
3 0
   f (#:~2#~#) 3674 2852 1571 3582 1402 3331 1741 2678 2076 2685 734 261
7 7
```

### Explanation

```
[:($#:I.@,)48879=4 4#.@,;._3]  Input: 2d array M
                            ]  Identity. Get M
                 4 4    ;._3   For each 4x4 subarray of M
                       ,         Flatten it
                    #.@          Convert it to decimal from binary
           48879=              Test if equal to 48879 (decimal value of beef)
[:(       )                    Operate on the resulting array
         ,                       Flatten it
      I.@                        Find the indices where true
    #:                           Convert from decimal to radix based on
   $                               The shape of that array
                               Returns the result as coordinates [y, x]
```

Comment: 24: `$#:(4 4$#:48879)I.@,@E.]` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/PSgNBDMbvPsWHK3QXtkv@TWayIBREQfDk3VOxiBffoK@@ZnooQj1MJpnJ98uX7@1@2Z3wuGKHGYQ1z37B0/vby/YwrKPB8rLWakyvy2E@PC8f23T3efz6wTivBp2wX3HCOKxnGc7DBK1MUHUCswVEjSBGFUaa/UUYUiR6qNCIzFgLVLxeufUfLosIlBPEhVpXZhbkOTARrRokxMHWqIdEFC9w1T9u/YYqNRxCFx2qKyytsXQa1248Sj6B3XJQfudO5Qpk8O361rKzUGpau4TOp1RackSbptn0z8Y5NCRLZ0Xh2H4B "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

```apl
⍸⎕⍷⍨~⊤0 8 0 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@j3h2P@qY@6t3@qHdF3aOuJQYKFgoGCmYgyf@caVyP2iZWA@VrD6141LvZ0IjLUAEEDYDQEAkacEFEYTIGMMiF4CGpVjDkQlaJRCKJo9jDhWIb3ESEvcjiyOaj6UARR3ITF6rpyOJItiH0cCGrRKgwBAA)

We already have [Zacharý's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97295/78410), but APL has improved a lot over the recent years, just enough to beat Jelly!

A full program that takes the binary matrix from stdin and prints the `(y,x)` to stdout.

#### How it works

```apl
⍸⎕⍷⍨~⊤0 8 0 6
     ⊤0 8 0 6  ⍝ Binary representation (a number → column)
               ⍝ 0 1 0 0
               ⍝ 0 0 0 1
               ⍝ 0 0 0 1
               ⍝ 0 0 0 0
    ~  ⍝ Boolean negation
 ⎕⍷⍨   ⍝ Take input and mark 1 where the 2D pattern appears
⍸      ⍝ Extract the coordinates of all ones
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```
def f(a);a=~/1011(.{8}1110){2}.{8}1111/;$`.size.divmod(12);end
```

It expects a string of `0` and `1` and returns an array of Y and X, zero-based.

[Try at ideone](http://ideone.com/AKhNf6).

Answer (score 1):

**Scala, 318 Bytes**

*This solution could be further improved... but I kept it readable and allowed for the input to be the multi-line spaced matrix.*

**Actual Solution if Array of binary String**

```
def has(s: String, t: String): Int = s.indexOf(t)
val beef = List("1011", "1110", "1110", "1111")
l.zipWithIndex.map{case(e,i)=>l.drop(i).take(4)}.map{_.zip(beef)}.map{_.collect{case e=>has(e._1,e._2)}}.zipWithIndex.filterNot{e => e._1.contains(-1) ||  e._1.distinct.length > 1}.map{e=>s"(${e._1.head},${e._2})"}.head
```

**Sample Working**

```
val bun = 
"""1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
""".replaceAll(" ","")
def has(s: String, t: String): Int = s.indexOf(t)
val beef = List("1011", "1110", "1110", "1111")
val l = bun.split("\n").toList
l.zipWithIndex.map{case(e,i)=>l.drop(i).take(4)}
.map{_.zip(beef)}
.map{_.collect{case e=>has(e._1,e._2)}}.zipWithIndex
.filterNot{e => e._1.contains(-1) ||  e._1.distinct.length > 1}
.map{e=>s"(${e._1.head},${e._2})"}.head
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 130 bytes

```
_144'{)"1-+2:';}144'["1-+19:~?1+~?!2+~?3+~?12+~?13+~?14+~?15+~?!24+~?25+~?26+~?27+~?!36+~?37+~?38+~?39+~?16'[&][12%2:`\ `-+12/`]']
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=XzE0NCd7KSIxLSsyOic7fTE0NCdbIjEtKzE5On4_MSt-PyEyK34_Myt-PzEyK34_MTMrfj8xNCt-PzE1K34_ITI0K34_MjUrfj8yNit-PzI3K34_ITM2K34_Mzcrfj8zOCt-PzM5K34_MTYnWyZdWzEyJTI6YFwgYC0rMTIvYF0nXQ&input=MTExMDAxMTExMTEwMTEwMTAwMTAwMDAwMDEwMDAxMTExMTAxMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAwMTExMTExMTExMDAwMDEwMTEwMTExMDAwMDAxMTAwMTExMTAwMDAxMTAwMTExMDExMTExMTExMTEwMDExMTExMTAwMDAxMDEwMTExMTEwMDExMDAwMDEx)

Takes input as one long string of 1s and 0s without any delimiters.  Outputs like `3 4` (0-based indexing).

This works by placing the input data into an "array" (basically a dictionary with integer keys) and then, for each possible starting value, tests the bits at particular offsets (all 16 of them in a very laborious process).

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 137 bytes** (according to Linux (thanks ElPedro))

```
def f(s,q=0):import re
 i=s.index(re.findall('1011.{8}1110.{8}1110.{8}1111',s)[q])+1
 x=i%12
 y=(i-x)/12
 if x>8:x,y=f(s,q+1)
 return x,y
```

Not exactly a competitive bytecount, but the algorithm is a bit interesting. Takes input as a string of binary values.

Comment: If you sue single spaces instead of 4 and check it on Linux it's 137

Comment: I think you need a newline and space before the import (I get an IndentError in Python 2 without it) which costs 2 bytes but you can then put i=..., x=... and y=... on the same line as  and separate with ; to lose 1 byte for 136

Comment: @elpedro I'm using Python 3, and it's fine with the import being on the same line.

Comment: Fully understood :)

Comment: Jeez, just reread my comments and I'm making so many typos tonight. Good thing I'm not trying to write any code...

Answer (score 1):

### Dyalog APL, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Takes a 12x12 binary array as user input and returns the coordinates in reverse order, the indexes start at 1.

Thanks to @Adám for saving many bytes.
-2 Bytes because I'm dumb and left everything in a function for no reason.

```
0~⍨∊{⍵×⍳⍴⍵}⎕⍷⍨~0 8 0 6⊤⍨4/2
```

Comment: Save 2 by replacing `~2 8 12∊⍨4 4⍴⍳16` with `15 7 15 9⊤⍨4/2`. Note that `0~⍨∊{⍵×⍳⍴⍵}` can be replaced with `⍸` from version 16.0 (your code only works in Dyalog APL).

Comment: Yeah, Dyalog has characters that differ from GNU. Or is it something else?

Comment: Well, `⍸` is being added from v16, I've been unable to find a list of GNUAPL primitives.

Comment: I've got GNU APL running, it's mostly just codepoint differences.

Comment: From what I've noticed.

Comment: `⍸⎕⍷⍨15 7 15 9⊤⍨4/2`

Comment: Does ⍸ work in GNU APL?

Comment: No, and what does that index char do?

Comment: ISn't that evaluated input?

Comment: From Dyalog APL version 16, `⍸` is `{⍵/⍳⍴⍵}`, i.e. the indices of the ones in a Boolean vector.

Comment: `⎕` is indeed evaluated input. This allows the user to directly enter a matrix `12 12⍴...` or enter the name of a predefined variable containing the data. The entire line is the body of a tradfn.

Comment: This whole sequence of exchanges somehow led me to believe v16 was released. Wow, I was just dumb.

Answer (score 1):

## **F# - 260 bytes**

Full program, including the required EntryPoint designator (so count fewer if you wish I suppose).

Input: each row as separate string:
"111001111110" "110100100000" "010001111101" "100100100100" "100101100111" "111111000010" "110111000001" "100111100001" "100111011111" "111110011111" "100001010111" "110011000011"

Code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main a=
 let rec f r:int=
  let b=a.[r].IndexOf"1011"
  if(b>0)then if(a.[r+1].[b..b+3].Equals"1110"&&a.[r+2].[b..b+3].Equals"1110"&&a.[r+3].[b..b+3].Equals"1111")then r else f(r+1)
  else f(r+1)
 printfn"%d%d"(a.[f 0].IndexOf"1011")(f 0);0
```

Not the most elegant solution most likely, but i wanted to keep with strings, so this is how i did it. I almost got it to be a single line and smaller using pipes, but there is something with the double if block that was getting me that i couldn't resolve. So oh well!

I thought too about porting Karl's answer into F# as it's a good one, and may still do that for fun as another approach, but wanted to stick with this one to be different.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 111 bytes

```r
function(a,b=63357%/%2^(0:15)%%2)
which(sapply(1:9,function(i)sapply(1:9,function(j)all(a[i+0:3,j+0:3]==b))),T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFdC4IwFIbv9z@EHRq0KRYJu@0XdBclm0xcmIofmL9@KdbaJF44@3jPy3PYWjMWqlVd2hcqlUrl3ORDlfW6rrAgkh@iKD4G@yC8Y5qwGIIgBDQWOitwJ5qmnDBLTsRGNPy7fYAoSyyuekeTiDyWeuNcAgC5gJnJcqj4U/StfuEMI0YW0VnMESVoXb4WtUK/o9vPlgTdJNbqGD4L@Uhq2yyceWiHsc14hjsZ8gme4SKZPxV1hv3sYXZCIqe2HvkZENr8JV6fFswb)

Searches for identities of 4x4 matrix starting at all indices of 9x9 matrix (to avoid edge overlaps).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2Fø€ü4}JJ˜Žùòbk9‰
```

Input as a matrix of bits. Output is 0-based, in the order \$Y,X\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyO3wjkdNaw7vMan18jo95@jewzsPb0rKtnzUsOH//@hoQx0QNABCQyRoEKsTDRGHyRnAIFAGwUfSoWMI1mOApscQqgfBQ7EPag/CFJi5yC5AlkG1B00XmgyS@1DsMcCQQbIXoQ/uAgM0txnGxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RVC7SkNREOzzFZJ6hbOP8xJEBLGwUbAMKRJNERUVvREsBPE7/ARBsRBFbXKx8i/yI3H2Ktgse3ZnZmfO2eVoPJ0sr/p7F5OmuV49v5ieNpPDlenp@axZW@lT73rMctQ@hbWt@Tv1@psHzWx08r9f3D3st4/rvf7urPkbLWW7fcW8/bCbnZ3v@6/P9q19Hh/Xxe3TkuYvG8vBQDMHUk2BmK2SqAUSC5ksqJFGYZIo1UsmrRUdaySVlIc0YBEhZcA5huJ7dDUk0gxgyUZSJRFbCV6gEFOkpAqu5JpIQrelnJQMZ1icw9lN1IgRcTLIYQ1/ETS1gncM2JTSFVcJ2BvQokVxGF7YGNJV8EysFLk6OSV2DIDimAg0F1jSmtxwQuQAB5bjL4yLFjfVcdk7YDWYh0PerEq4iFIzE/4ONDdkiIRvwS3pmB6qRMhFh0UXNiRQVWhmAy5BTkJGllQiZfw9bA@HPw).

**Explanation:**

```python
2Fø€ü4}     # Create transposed overlapping 4x4 blocks of the (implicit) input-matrix:
2F          #  Loop 2 times:
  ø         #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
   €        #   Map over each row:
    ü4      #    Create all overlapping quartets
 }          #  Close the loop
J           # Join each row of each matrix together
 J          # Join the rows of each matrix together
  ˜         # Flatten the list of strings
   Žùò      # Push compressed integer 63481
      b     # Convert it to binary: 1111011111111001
       k    # Get the index of this binary-string in the list
        9‰  # Divmod it by 9
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Žùò` is `63481`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 12 bytes

```
⊚⌕⋯13_7_7_15
```

Self explanatory. Converts the number array to bits, finds where it is. The input is a 12x12 bit matrix, the output is a 1x2 matrix where the X coordinate is the second element.

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAg4oqa4oyV4ouvMTNfN183XzE1CgpGIOKJoeKHjOKLryBbMzcxMCAzMzYwIDExNDkgMjM0MCAyNDA3IDQwMzQgMzUyMSAyNTI5IDI1MjcgMzk5OSAyMTM1IDMyNjddCkYg4omh4oeM4ouvIFsxMjIyIDMxMDcgMTUwOCAzOTk3IDE5MDYgMzc5IDI4NzQgMjkyNiAxNDgwIDE0ODcgMzU2NSA2MzNdCkYg4omh4oeM4ouvIFsyNzk2IDIwNiAxNDggNzYzIDQyOSAxMjc0IDIxNzAgMjQ5NSA0MiAxNjQ2IDM2MyAxMTQ1XQo=)