# Count trailing truths

Tags: code-golf, number, array, counting, logic

## Inspired by, and in memory of, my dear friend and colleague,

[image: Dan Baronet]

## [Dan Baronet](http://www.dyalog.com/blog/2016/11/dan-baronet/), 1956 – 2016. [R.I.P.](http://danielbaronet.rip/)

He found [the shortest possible APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98764/43319) to this task:

#### Task

Given a Boolean list, count the number of trailing truth values.

#### Example cases

`{}` → `0`

`{0}` → `0`

`{1}` → `1`

`{0, 1, 1, 0, 0}` → `0`

`{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}` → `1`

`{1, 1, 0, 1, 1}` → `2`

`{0, 0, 1, 1, 1}` → `3`

`{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` → `6`

Comment: Can we take the list as a string of zeros and ones? e.g. `01100`?

Comment: @Adnan only if that is the most normal way for your language to represent boolean lists.

Comment: Sorry for your loss.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thank you. It will be tough going forward. Dan taught me all I needed to know to work for Dyalog.

Comment: Farewell to Dan. RIP...

Comment: Are we allowed to take the input as actual bits in a row instead of individual bytes? i.e. {1,0,1,0} would be 1010000 not 10000000 00000000 10000000 00000000

Comment: @moonheart08 Only if that is the most normal way for your language to represent boolean lists.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, <s>6</s> 2 bytes

```
⊥⍨
```

Test it on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u22A5%u2368%29%A8%28%u236C%280%29%281%29%280%201%201%200%200%29%281%201%201%200%201%29%281%201%200%201%201%29%280%200%201%201%201%29%281%201%201%201%201%201%29%29&run).

#### How it works

**⊥** (uptack, dyadic: decode) performs base conversion. If the left operand is a vector, it performs *mixed* base conversion, which is perfect for this task.

For a base vector **b = b<sub>n</sub>, ⋯, b<sub>0</sub>** and a digit vector **a = a<sub>n</sub>, ⋯, a<sub>0</sub>**, **b ⊥ a** converts **a** to the mixed base **b**, i.e., it computes **b<sub>0</sub>⋯b<sub>n-1</sub>a<sub>n</sub> + ⋯ + b<sub>0</sub>b<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>**.

Now, **⍨** (tilde dieresis, commute) modifies the operator to the left as follows. In a monadic context, it calls the operator with equal left and right arguments.

For example, **⊥⍨ a** is defined as **a ⊥ a**, which computes **a<sub>0</sub>⋯a<sub>n</sub> + ⋯ + a<sub>0</sub>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>**, the sum of all cumulative products from the right to the left.

For **k** trailing ones, the **k** rightmost products are **1** and all others are **0**, so their sum is equal to **k**.

Comment: Hint: Dan did it in only two bytes.

Comment: Mixed base conversion! That's clever.

Comment: Oh. Mixed base conversion, how it [strikes again.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79653/31957)

Comment: Bravo! In fact, because of Dan, we special-cased `b⊥b` and `⊥⍨b` giving up to infinite speed-up.

Answer (score 19):

### JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

```js
f=l=>l.pop()?f(l)+1:0
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=l=>l.pop()?f(l)+1:0

console.log(f([])); // → 0
console.log(f([0])); // → 0
console.log(f([1])); // → 1
console.log(f([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])); // → 0
console.log(f([1, 1, 1, 0, 1])); // → 1
console.log(f([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])); // → 2
console.log(f([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])); // → 3
console.log(f([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // → 6
```

Comment: How does this work? How does `f(l)+1` return a value `> 2`?

Comment: @Oliver This is a recursive process, evaluated as `l.pop()?(l.pop()?(l.pop()?(...etc...)+1:0)+1:0)+1:0`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ŒrṪP
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJy4bmqUA&input=&args=WzEsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDFd) or [Verify all test cases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJy4bmqUArDh-KCrA&input=&args=W1tdLCBbMF0sIFsxXSwgWzAsIDEsIDEsIDAsIDBdLCBbMSwgMSwgMSwgMCwgMV0sIFsxLCAxLCAwLCAxLCAxXSwgWzAsIDAsIDEsIDEsIDFdLCBbMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMV1d)

For the case where the list is empty, there are some curious observations. First, run-length encoding the empty list `[]` returns another empty list `[]`. Then retreiving the last element from that using tail `Ṫ` returns `0` instead of a pair `[value, count]` which are the regular elements of a run-length encoded array. Then product `P` returns `0` when called on `0` which is the expected result.

### Explanation

```
ŒrṪP  Main link. Input: list M
Œr    Run-length encode
  Ṫ   Tail, get the last value
   P  Product, multiply the values together
```

Comment: Alternatively, `ŒgṪS` works, too!

Comment: It gives the right output for the empty list as input, but I'm surprised given the dissection. Would you mind walking through that special case?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm surprised too that it worked. Also, I just noticed that the first link has the wrong code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor `Ṫ` in Jelly is implemented as: `lambda z: iterable(z).pop() if iterable(z) else 0`. `iterable` when called on a list just returns the list, and the empty list is of course falsy.

Answer (score 12):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
@]#=+
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QF0jPSs&input=WzE6MTowOjE6MV0&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
@]        A suffix of the Input...
  #=      ...whose elements are all equal
    +     Sum its elements
```

Since `@] - Suffix` starts from the biggest suffix all the way up to the smallest one, it will find the longest run first.

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```haskell
a%b|b=1+a|0<3=0
foldl(%)0
```

Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> foldl(%)0 [True,False,True,True]
2
```

Pointfree version (26 bytes):

```haskell
length.fst.span id.reverse
```

---

Using an integer list instead of a bool list (21 bytes, thanks to Christian Sievers):

```haskell
a%b=b*(a+1)
foldl(%)0
```

Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> foldl(%)0 [1,0,1,1]
2
```

Pointfree version (25 bytes)

```haskell
sum.fst.span(==1).reverse
```

Comment: For integer lists the `foldl` idea works with `a%b=b*(a+1)`

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *carusocomputing*.

```
Î0¡¤g
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w44wwqHCpGc&input=MTEwMTEx)

**Explanation**

```
Î      # push 0 and input
 0¡    # split on 0
   ¤   # take last item in list
    g  # get length
```

Comment: `0¡¤g` is four bytes.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Nice! It wasn't yet clarified if string input was okay when I wrote this, but I see now that it is :)

Comment: `J0¡¤g` is also still shorter ;).

Comment: @carusocomputing: Unfortunately we need `Î` to handle the empty input, but it's still a byte saved thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

### CJam (8 bytes)

```
{W%0+0#}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B'%E2%86%92%2F0%3D'%2C-~~%5D%0A%0A%7BW%250%2B0%23%7D%0A%0A~p%7D%2F&input=%7B%7D%20%E2%86%92%200%0A%7B0%7D%20%E2%86%92%200%0A%7B1%7D%20%E2%86%92%201%0A%7B0%2C%201%2C%201%2C%200%2C%200%7D%20%E2%86%92%200%0A%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%200%2C%201%7D%20%E2%86%92%201%0A%7B1%2C%201%2C%200%2C%201%2C%201%7D%20%E2%86%92%202%0A%7B0%2C%200%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%7D%20%E2%86%92%203%0A%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%7D%20%E2%86%92%206)

#### Dissection

```
{    e# begin a block
  W%  e# reverse the array
  0+  e# append 0 so there's something to find
  0#  e# find index of first 0, which is number of nonzeros before it
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 31 bytes

```
lambda a:(a[::-1]+[0]).index(0)
```

Answer (score 9):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
r`1\G
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApyYDFcRw&input=CjAKMQowMTEwMAoxMTEwMQoxMTAxMQowMDExMQoxMTExMTE) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Defining the input format for Retina isn't entirely unambiguous. Since Retina has no concept of any type except strings (and also no value that can be used for our usual definition of truthy and falsy), I usually use `0` and `1` (or something positive in general) to correspond to truthy and falsy, as they represent zero or some matches, respectively.

With single-character representations, we also don't need a separator for the list (which in a way, is more the more natural list representation for a language that only has strings). [Adám confirmed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98730/count-trailing-truths?noredirect=1#comment239932_98773) that this is an acceptable input format.

As for the regex itself, it matches from `r`ight to left and `\G` anchors each match to the previous one. Hence, this counts how many `1`s we can match from the end of the string.

Comment: "Yes, for Retina, being that it handles only strings, I think a "01" or "FT" string is in order.

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
PYps
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UFlwcw&input=WzEsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDFd)

```
P       % Flip
 Yp     % Cumulative product
   s    % Sum
```

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
Fold[If[#2,#+1,0]&,0,#]&
```

Comment: Just recording a port of Dan's cool mixed-base solution: `FromDigits[b=Boole@#,MixedRadix@b]&` (35 bytes).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṣ0ṪL
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmjMOG5qkw&input=&args=WzEsMSwwLDEsMV0)**, or [all tests](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmjMOG5qkwKw4figqw&input=&args=W1tdLFswXSxbMV0sWzAsMSwxLDAsMF0sWzEsMSwxLDAsMV0sWzEsMSwwLDEsMV0sWzAsMCwxLDEsMV0sWzEsMSwxLDEsMSwxXV0)

#### How?

```
ṣ0ṪL - Main link: booleanList
ṣ0   - split on occurrences of 0 ([] -> [[]]; [0] -> [[],[]]; [1] -> [[1]]; ...)
  Ṫ  - tail (rightmost entry)
   L - length
```

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, 6 bytes

```
x_+0Q0
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=x_%2B0Q0&input=%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%5D&debug=0)

Appends a 0, reverses and finds the index of the first 0

Comment: @Jakube fixed now - different algorithm

Answer (score 6):

## J, <s>9</s> 3 bytes

```
#.~
```

This is reflexive mixed base conversion. [Because this is the same as mixed base conversion.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98764/31957) [Again.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79653/31957)

### Test cases

```
   v =: #.~
   ]t =: '';0;1;0 1 1 0 0;1 1 1 0 1;1 1 0 1 1;0 0 1 1 1;1 1 1 1 1 1
++-+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
||0|1|0 1 1 0 0|1 1 1 0 1|1 1 0 1 1|0 0 1 1 1|1 1 1 1 1 1|
++-+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
   v&.> t
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|1|0|1|2|3|6|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   (,. v&.>) t
+-----------+-+
|           |0|
+-----------+-+
|0          |0|
+-----------+-+
|1          |1|
+-----------+-+
|0 1 1 0 0  |0|
+-----------+-+
|1 1 1 0 1  |1|
+-----------+-+
|1 1 0 1 1  |2|
+-----------+-+
|0 0 1 1 1  |3|
+-----------+-+
|1 1 1 1 1 1|6|
+-----------+-+
```

Comment: Hint: This can be done in only 3 bytes, using the J translation of Dan's solution.

Comment: @Adám I tried looking for a solution. Didn't think of base conversion. That's really quite clever of him!

Comment: Yes. That was Dan. :-(

Answer (score 5):

## C90 (gcc), 46 bytes

```c
r;main(c,v)int**v;{while(0<--c&*v[c])r++;c=r;}
```

Input is via command-line arguments (one integer per argument), output via [exit code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5330/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoJunoF5knZuYmaeRrFOmmZlXoqVVZl1dnpGZk6phYKOrm6ymVRadHKtZpK1tnWxbZF2rrmCnkFxSopfMlZ6crKBbXJJim2xpoKCbDxKFyujpA2lrBbANKvYQroIBuoAhhgoFQyA0wKISKmGITQKsC9MoiGGG2I1Clfr/HwA)

#### How it works

**r** is a global variable. Its type defaults to *int* and, being global, it value defaults to **0**.

The function argument **c** defaults to *int* as well. It will hold the integer **n + 1** for arrays of **n** Booleans; the first argument of **main** is always the path of the executable.

The function argument **v** is declared as `int**`. The actual type of **v** will be `char**`, but since we'll only examine the least significant bit of each argument to tell the characters **0** (code point **48**) and **1** (code point **49**) apart, this won't matter on little-endian machines.

The while loop decrements **c** and compares it to **0**. Once **c** reaches **0**, we'll break out of the loop. This is needed only if the array contains no **0**'s.

As long as `0<--c` returns **1**, we takes the **c**<sup>th</sup> command-line argument (`v[c]`) and extract its first character with by dereferencing the pointer (`*`). We take the bitwise AND of the Boolean `0<--c` and the code point of the character (and three garbage bytes that follow it), so the condition will return **0** once a **0** is encountered, breaking out of the loop.

In the remaining case, while the command-line arguments are **1**, `r++` increments **r** by **1**, thus counting the number of trailing **1**'s.

Finally, `c=r` stores the computed value of **r** in **c**. With default settings, the compiler optimize and remove the assignment; it actually generates the `movl %eax, -4(%rbp)` instruction. Since `ret` returns the value of the EAX register, this generates the desired output.

Note that this code does *not* work with C99, which returns **0** from *main* if the end of *main* is reached.

Comment: Isn´t `argc` at least `1` (with `argv[0]` containing the file name)? You could save one byte with `--c&&` instead of `0<--c&`. gcc´s exit code is taken from `argc`? Neat.

Comment: @Titus That won't work. `*v[c]` is the code point of **1** or **0**, so it's either **49** or **48** and thus always truthy.

Comment: With C89 and C90, gcc returns whatever is in RAX at that moment. C99 always returns **0** from main if the end is reached.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <strike>40 39</strike> 25 bytes

Completely reworked solution thanks to @Dason

```
sum(cumprod(rev(scan())))
```

Read input from stdin, reverse the vector and if the first element of is `!=0` then output the the first length of the run-length encoding (`rle`), else `0`.

Comment: You can save a byte by changing the second line to `ifelse(r$v,r$l,0)[1]`. (Vectorized if, and then take the first element.)

Comment: no need for the iflelse - just multiply r$v and r$l.

Comment: But the sum(cumprod(rev(.))) route should save a lot of bytes anyways

Answer (score 4):

## k, 6 bytes

```
+/&\|:
```

This function composition translates to `sum mins reverse` in `q`, the language's more readable sibling, where mins is a rolling minimum.

Comment: Can the : be dropped?

Comment: A [port](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpCv6L2f1q0okEsV1o0mDAEsxQMgdBAASIC5RjCOGBZiDKIQkOEMgj3PwA) of APL version is possible in [ngn/k](https://git.sr.ht/~ngn/k) for 5 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, <s>10</s> 6 bytes

```
_0+0R@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=_0%2B0R%40&input=%5B1%2C++1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 24 bytes

```haskell
foldl(\a b->sum[a+1|b])0
```

Iterates over the list, adding one for each element, resetting to `0` after it hits a `False`.

**16 bytes** with 0/1 input:

```haskell
foldl((*).(+1))0
```

If the list were guaranteed non-empty, we could get 14 bytes:

```haskell
sum.scanr1(*)1
```

This computes the cumulative product from the back, then sums them. The cumulative product remains 1 until a 0 is hit, and then becomes 0. So, the 1's correspond to trailing 1's.

Answer (score 3):

## C#6, <s>103</s> 72 bytes

```
using System.Linq;
int a(bool[] l)=>l.Reverse().TakeWhile(x=>x).Count();
```

Using non-generic list beats generic list by 1 byte lol

-31 bytes thanks to Scott

Comment: If you use an array of `int`s, you can get away with `int a(int[] l)=>l.Reverse().TakeWhile(i=>i>0).Sum();`

Comment: @Scott Of course what was I thinking... I will stick with bool though. Question specifies boolean list and it's not C.

Comment: Compile to a `Func<bool[], int>` for 57 bytes i.e. `using System.Linq;l=>l.Reverse().TakeWhile(x=>x).Count();`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-hx`, 3 bytes

```
i ô
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=aSD0&input=LWh4ClswLCAwLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAxXQ==)

Japt's flag combinations rock.

#### How it works

```
Ui ô

Ui  Insert `undefined` at index 0
ô   Split at falsy items

-h  Take last element
-x  Sum
```

If we didn't have to handle the special case `[]`, we could get away with 1 byte `ô`, winning over APL.

Comment: Half the job is done by flags‽

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 22 bytes

21 bytes of code + 1 byte for `-p` flag.

```pl
s/.(?=.*0)//g;$_=y;1;
```

To run it :

```
perl -pE 's/.(?=.*0)//g;$_=y;1;' <<< "0 1 1 0 1 1 1"
```

(Actually, the format of the input doesn't matter a lot : `0110111`, `0 1 1 0 1 1 1`, `[0,1,1,0,1,1,1]` etc. would all work)

---

**18 bytes version** from [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings) but it requires to supply the input as a string of 0 and 1, which isn't allowed :

```
perl -pE '/1*$/;$_=length$&' <<< '0110111'
```

Comment: Loving that `;` trick :) If format is one continuous string: `perl -pE '/1*$/;$_=length$&' <<< '0110111'` for 18, not sure if that's bending the rules or not though...

Comment: @DomHastings yea, me too! (Thanks Ton for showing me that!) The first and second comments of the question kinda disallow the format of input you need for your solution... But I'll edit my post to suggest your version if the format of the input was more free.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 37 bytes

```
f=lambda l:len(l)and-~f(l[:-1])*l[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [DASH](https://github.com/molarmanful/DASH), 16 bytes

```
@len mstr"1+$"#0
```

It's not the shortest possible DASH solution, but the shortest possible DASH solution is bugging out on me. I'm posting this novel approach in its place.

Usage:

```
(@len mstr"1+$"#0)"100111"
```

## Explanation

```
@(                 #. Lambda
  len (            #. Get the length of the array after...
    mstr "1+$" #0  #. ... matching the argument with regex /1+$/
  )                #. * mstr returns an empty array for no matches
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 25 bytes

```
l=>l.reverse:+0 indexOf 0
```

Ungolfed:

```
l=>(l.reverse :+ 0).indexOf(0)
```

Reverses the list, appends a 0 and find the first index of 0, which is the number of elements before the first 0

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 57 bytes

```
@set n=0
@for %%n in (%*)do @set/an=n*%%n+%%n
@echo %n%
```

Takes input as command-line parameters. Works by multiplying the accumulator by the current value before adding it on, so that any zeros in the command line reset the count. Note that `%%n` is not the same as the `n` or `%n%` variable.

Answer (score 2):

### GolfSharp, 14 bytes

```
n=>n.V().O(F);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 62 bytes

```
int c(boolean[]a){int r=0;for(boolean b:a)r=b?r+1:0;return r;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/CX1cOb)

```
class M{
  static int c(boolean[] a){
    int r = 0;
    for (boolean b : a){
      r = b ? r+1 : 0;
    }
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{}) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ false }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ true }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ false, true, true, false, false }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ true, true, true, false, true }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ true, true, false, true, true }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ false, false, true, true, true }) + ", ");
    System.out.print(c(new boolean[]{ true, true, true, true, true, true }));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5.10, 22 bytes

21 bytes + 1 byte for `-a` flag.
Since the regex-based expression was done... :p

The input values for the array must be separated by a space.

```
$n++while pop@F;say$n
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/SaIsrK)

Comment: Slightly shorter if you take arguments via command line: `perl -E '$_++while pop;say' 0 1 1 0 1 1 1` but this doesn't output anything for `0` (not sure if that's a problem though!)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```
->n{n.size-1-(n.rindex(!0)||-1)}
```

Creates an anonymous function that finds the right-most instance of a false value, and counts the size of the subarray starting at that value.

It uses `!0` as false, as 0 are truthy values in Ruby. `rindex` finds the last index of a value in an array.

**Usage**:

```
boolean_list = [true, false, false, true]
->n{n.size-1-(n.rindex(!0)||-1)}[boolean_list]
```

**Returns** 1

---

If I was allowed to be passed a string of 0s and 1s as command line parameters (which is not how ruby represents lists of booleans), I could get it down to 24:

```
$*[0]=~/(1*)\z/;p$1.size
```

This uses regular expressions and prints the length of the string returned by the regular expression `/(1*)\z/`, where `\z` is the end of the string. `$*[0]` is the first argument passed and is a string of 0s and 1s.

Usage:

```
trailing_truths.rb 011101
```

Returns 1.

Comment: Once you have the index of the last false value, why do you need to retrieve elements from the array again?

Comment: You're right, I don't. Thanks. 5 bytes off!

Answer (score 2):

## C++17, <s>82</s> 66 bytes

```c++
int f(){return 0;}int f(int H,auto... L){return(H*...*L)+f(L...);}
```

Uses the C++17 template parameter fold expression and essentially the same idea as [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98764/53667). Saving 16 bytes by using Generic Variadic Lambda.

Explanation:

```c++
int f(){return 0;} //base case for empty list
  
int f(int H, auto... L) { //first element, variadic arguments
    return (H*...*L)      //a_0*a_1*a_2*...
         + f(L...);       //+ f(a_1,a_2,...)
}
```

Usage:

```c++
f(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1) -> 5
f() -> 0
f(1,0,1,0) -> 0
```

### Non competing

Albeit longer, this also works with template constants:

```c++
template <int...L> int C=0;
template <int H, int...L> int C<H,L...> = (H*...*L)+C<L...>;
```

Usage:

```c++
std::cout << C<1,0,1,1>  << std::endl;
std::cout << C<1,0,1,0,1>  << std::endl;
std::cout << C<1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1>  << std::endl;
std::cout << C<1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1>  << std::endl;
std::cout << C<> << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```
<?=strlen(preg_filter('/.*[^1]/','',join($argv)));
```

Weirdly my first try with a regex turned out shorter than my try with arrays...

Use like:

```
php tt.php 1 1 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
WDQg++ii
```

Takes input as command-line arguments of `0` and `1` (or any truthy value). [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=V0RRZysraWk&input=&args=MQ+MA+MQ+MQ)

#### Explanation

```
          g is cmdline args, i is 0
 DQg      Dequeue item from end of g
W   ++i   While this is truthy, increment i
       i  Print i
```

(Dequeueing from an empty list gives nil, which is falsey.)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>40</s> 34 bytes

Along with `$argv` comes `$argc` ... and both are variable.
Either one of the arguments or `+$argv[0]`==`+"-"` is `0`.

```
while(+$argv[--$argc])$i++;echo$i;
```

takes input from command line arguments. Empty output for `0`.
Run with `php -nr '<code>' <space separated values>`

**unary output, <s>35</s> 29 bytes**

```
while(+$argv[--$argc])echo 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, 99 bytes

Takes input like `11011`. Output is a single byte/character value.

```
-[>+<-----]>---[>>,]<-[>+<-----]>---[-<+>>>+<<]<[->+<]>+>>+[<+[-<<+>>]<<<[-<+>>>-<<]<[->+<]>>>-]<-.
```

[**Try it online**](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LVs-KzwtLS0tLV0-LS0tWz4-LF08LVs-KzwtLS0tLV0-LS0tWy08Kz4-Pis8PF08Wy0-KzxdPis-PitbPCtbLTw8Kz4-XTw8PFstPCs-Pj4tPDxdPFstPis8XT4-Pi1dPC0u) - Run with input, then click "view memory" to see the value under the pointer that was printed.

**Explanation:**

```
-[>+<-----]>---             put constant 48 (ASCII '0') at start of list
[>>,]                       receive all input, with an empty cell between each
<-[>+<-----]>---            constant 48 near end of list
[-<+>>>+<<]<[->+<]>+>>      move to right and copy right, add one to make 49 (ASCII '1')
                            TAPE: 48 _ i0 _ i1 _ ... in _ 49 _ 48< (pointer)

+[<+[-<<+>>]<<              LOOP. Put counter+=1 in empty cell. Move it left 2 cells.
<[-<+>>>-<<]<[->+<]>        Subtract value from value 2 cells right.
>>-]<-.                     Subtract one more. If zero, print counter-1, Else loop again.
```

---

Close, but must contain a zero, and it doesn't handle trailing zeros or an empty list. (49 bytes)

```
,[>>,]>>+[<+[-<<+>>]<<<[-<+>>>-<<]<[->+<]>>>-]<-.
```

Comment: `,[>,]-[>+<-----]>---[-<<[<]>[->]>]<<[>[-<+>]<<]>.`

Comment: @JoKing Go ahead and create your own answer. That doesn't resemble mine at all.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 6 bytes

```
$v;FL#
```

Arguments given a list on command line: `$ pushy truths.pshy 0,1,1,0,0.` Like my [binary conversion program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter), this takes advantage of the second stack in an interesting way. Here's how it works:

```
         \ Implicit: Input on stack
$        \ While last item is not 0:
 v;      \   Move last item to auxiliary stack
   FL#   \ Output length of auxiliary stack.
```

Note that the loop will not run if the list is empty, so the output will be `0`.

Comment: How many stacks does Pushy have?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Two, input is automatically on stack 1 and that's where main operations take place. Stack 2 is just for storing counters / variables that need to be kept out of the way.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 38 bytes

a totally different approach

```
<?=strpos(strrev(join([0]+$argv)),48);
```

takes input from command line arguments. Save to file.

`[0]+$argv` sets the first element (script name) to `0`.
Join that without a delimiter, reverse and find the first occurence of the `0` character.

While [my first solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102439#102439) works with any truthy and falsy values, this one obviously depends on single characters: `0` is falsy, every other character (apart from maybe the `0` byte) truthy.

Comment: -4 Bytes for using `$_GET`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann That would have empty output for any list full of `1`s.

Comment: Okay now I have realize it

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 30 bytes

```
p->valuation(Pol(p)*(x-1)+1,x)
```

Converts the list to a polynomial, say \$p\$, then finds the valuation of \$(x-1)p+1\$ with respect to \$x\$, i.e., the minimal degree of its nonzero terms.

For example, if we take `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` as input, then the polynomial \$p\$ is \$x^4 + x^2 + x + 1\$, and \$(x-1)p+1\$ is \$x^5 - x^4 + x^3\$, whose valuation is \$3\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtLCoAwDESvElw12oI5gJ7BvbjoRimUGkRFT19brT8Iw@Qxj/Vk1MC@hwo8q3rVdtGzGZ1oRisYc7EpwoLkhl4z210wqBp4Mm4ONYtPBn1YooS27UKUMehsEui8UC76AfSCtEvKY9FPuVmH/gA)

Comment: Well, that is truly an original method. +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>1580</s> <s>1576</s> 1564 bytes

*-4 bytes because of a less complex route to the Crime Lab (string equality checker). Also, you don't run out of gas for a sufficiently large number of truthy values anymore!*

*-12 bytes by getting rid of the quotes.*

```
Go to the Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.
[B]
Switch to plan C if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 3 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Go to Zoom Zoom:n.
Go to Narrow Path Park:w 1 l 1 l 1 r.
Go to Joyless Park:e 1 r 3 l.
Go to Chop Suey:w 1 r 1 r 1 l.
Switch to plan B.
[C]
0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 3 l 3 l 2 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park:w 1 r.
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 r 1 r 1 l 1 r.
[D]
Switch to plan F if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
1 is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 l 1 r 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
Go to Zoom Zoom:n.
Go to Crime Lab:w 1 l 2 r.
Switch to plan E if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 l 1 l 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:n 1 r 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 l 1 l 1 l.
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 r 1 r 1 l 1 r.
Switch to plan D.
[E]
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 5 l.
[F]
Go to Sunny Skies Park:w 1 l 1 r 2 l 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
Go to Taxi Garage:n 1 r 1 l 1 r.
```

Input is in the form of a string of 0's and 1's (for example: `11101`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVXfb4IwEH7nr7i3vZnpthfe/J0sizPBZMmMDxUrNNaWtCWMv54VECx1wjTLCC3huH53/e7rodAXybI5B6XvEMOSSwXv@z3xsZtAH6geIn/2nCXxD3EECCIkJWYBFhBwwoJ86TjkEXgxTntOiVUbXFYhwHOFtB5tHC8hyg9z14giBmMge2AcOMNAJCSIKA3dETT1qfavQ5avRUAKT10pL5AQPIElUqGexKHd@5WnFEt58iwDfnJ@LCaXVSYbtOaw4LHyMsFcXPBTpGtTl5yoO9FmUTbSRI43zqPBFyAFnkLCDwndwSI@YsEpD@qq/PTtzFcxBnmabUx4MWMpeAeCm2zY9jL7q8Qwc2@l53pyIYvZPbIQ5IjhDW17Tt/i5kMQhcWDhAmOuKpya1oN2Q86ZX8OdVUStc8JuCDY2ub0jm2u9GkdoS2meyJDLOoa23ZXtuMMdzsdjTMYUno@vxfVZE0h347YtDbq/1eKM3OktyjPKsdEa3G6ub7@pWhis02b8msFdTfP31fSaMgdnBl9vIIzWzuzW9JK/wdgjgQKsNGxc4cs6//DlX0D)

Taxi is an esolang in which all programming is done by picking up and dropping off passengers at various stops in the fictional town of Townsburg. Of course, your taxicab will sometimes run out of gas, so you also need to visit gas stations every so often, and pay using the credits you receive as fare.

I had to do some strange management of fuel in this program. Specifically, I have a loop at the beginning (between plans `B` and `C`) which pushes each character of the input to `Narrow Path Park` (which is a LIFO queue, or a stack) by going back and forth between `Narrow Path Park` and `Chop Suey` (which split the input string into characters in the first place). However, for sufficiently large inputs, this can cause me to run out of gas. Simply going to a gas station every iteration is insufficient, because I'm not earning enough money from actually bringing passengers to their destinations. The best way I've figured out to earn enough money to make going to a gas station every iteration "worth it" is bringing each new passenger to `Cyclone` (which clones them), and taking one of those clones to `Narrow Path Park` while leaving one forever trapped at `Joyless Park` (which is a FIFO queue, but for the purposes of this program is a dumping ground).

(Note: Bringing passengers to `Riverview Bridge` is a good way to get rid of them, but they don't pay you - because they always seem to fall off the bridge into the river before they can pay - so I couldn't do this either.)

Comment: [1531 bytes (STDERR ignored)](https://tio.run/##vVRNb4MwDL3zK3zbrVq77cKtn5OmqavEpEmrOKQ0QNQ0QUkQ49ez8NlAV1iraQiCMM6z/fxihb5Ilj1zUPoOMWy4VPDm@8TDdgJjoPoR@XtkbYh3iCNAECEpMQuwgIATFuRb5yGPwIlxOrJKrMZgsxoBHmuk7cy1nIQoL8xdI4oYzIH4wDhwhoFISBBRGnogaOpR7d@ELD@LgBQehlJeIyF4AhukQr2IQ7/3C08plrLyLAN@cn4sFpvVpi5ow2HBY@1lgtm44KdIt0tdUlFX0dahbKaJnLvWvcEXIAWOQsILCd3DOj5iwSkPmq789O/EV/FM8jT7mHBixlJwDgS32ejay@wvEsPM2krP7eJMFqtbZCHIEcMr2o2scYebD0EUFncSFjjiqs6tbTVkPxmU/SnURUk0PhVwQXCnzOUNZb7r0zpDO0x9IkMsmh537bbsx5nu9zoaZzCl9HR@z7rJ2kK@HrFtbfX/rxRn5kivUV6nHQutxaV7ef9TMcRWbp/yGwUND8/fd9IYyAOcGXO8hjNHO2tqz7LxP1zZNw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 30 bytes

```
(()){{}({}{{}}<><{}>)<>([])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0NTs7q6VqO6FkjW2tjZVNfaadrYaUTHagJ5////N/hvCIYw2hAA)

### Explanation

```
(()) #{ Start Loop.  Used instead of ([]) so that the loop will run at least once on empty input. }
{{}  #{Remove the stack height. }
 (
  {}{{}}  #{ Add the TOS with any 1s below it (until a zero). }
  <><{}>  #{ Remove a value on the other stack if there. }
 )     #{ Push the result (# of 1s just removed) to the other stack. } 
 <>    #{ Switch stacks back. }
 ([])  #{ Push stack height for the loop. }
}  #{ Once the loop is done (stack is empty)... }
<> #{ Switch stacks to the most recent # of 1s removed. }
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
Ġt
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBcyIsIiIsIsSgdCIsIiIsIltdXG5bMF1cblsxXVxuWzAsIDEsIDEsIDAsIDBdXG5bMSwgMSwgMSwgMCwgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAwLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDFdIl0=)

Tied with first!

#### Explained

```
Ġt∑
Ġ   # group by consecutive
 t  # tail
```

`s` flag does sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 17 bytes

```
{sum [\R*] 0,|@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0VyE6JkgrVsFAp8YhvvZ/cWKlgpJKvIKtnUJ1moJKfK2SQlp@kYKGpo6ChltiTnGqDogVUlQKYUCEFMB8KAkVAlNwtdhUgDjoCjDMQ7IEi13YjMBOav4HAA)

- `0, |@_` is the input list of boolean values with a zero prepended to the front.
- `R*` is the `R`eversed multiplication operator.  It's the same as the regular multiplication operator `*`, except that it's right-associative.
- `[\R*]` is the "triangular reduction" of the list to the right, using the `R*` operator.  Given a list \$x_0, x_1, ... x_n\$, it produces \$x_n, x_n \cdot x_{n-1}, x_n \cdot x_{n-1} \cdot x_{n-2}, ..., x_n \cdot x_{n-1} \cdot x_{n-2} \cdot ... \cdot x_0\$.  Raku's arithmetic operators treat boolean true values as 1 and false values as 0, so this produces a list that starts with as many ones as there are true values at the end of the list, followed by as many zeroes as there are remaining values in the list.
- `sum` adds up those values.

It's necessary to paste a leading zero onto the front of the input list, or else an empty list would produce the multiplicative identity element 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Python2, <s>42</s> 41 Byes

```
t=input()[::-1];print len(t[:t.index(0)])
```

takes input as [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

Comment: No joy with the empty list test case.

Answer (score 1):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 14 bytes

```
c7iA)7a!xcx!Bp
```

Accepts the formatting `[0,1,0,1,0`, where any non-numeric character can be replaced with any other non-numeric character.  Empty input is the empty list.

Explanation:  Every `7` input number `i` is queued up `A`; every "0" input number (or rather, non-"1") `)7` will pop from the queue until it's empty `7a!x`; before another input number is queued, a delimiter character is grabbed `cx` to check for the end of queue.  After all the integers are grabbed, `!Bp` prints the length of the queue of input numbers (which will be all the trailing "1" values.)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>58</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
function f($a){while(array_pop($a))$i++;return+$i;}
```

Since PHP has no list I use an array instead

-4 bytes thanks to  user59178

[All tests](http://ideone.com/GJ29F1)

Comment: Assigning `$i=0;` is unnecessary if you echo/return `+$i`. Having this as a command line program rather than a function is much shorter as well, though you need to account for the fact that $argv[0] is truthy. With both of these you could save 19 bytes.

Comment: `return+$i;` needs no space.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 49 bytes

```
func a(b:[Bool]){print(b.reduce(0,{$1 ?$0+1:0}))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 32 bytes

```
0$nI1-[1=?v0g1+1R]N.
      .Ng0<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#@2@gkudpqBttaGtfZpBuqG0YFOunx6UABnp@6QY2////N1QwVDAAYkMA)

#### Explanation

```
0                             pushes 0 (this is the number that will keep track of the number of 1s)
 $n                           pushes all of input as numbers (pushes -1 if there is no input)
   I1-                        pushes stack minus 1 (to exclude the 0)
      [          ]            for loop with the previous number as the number of iterations
       1=?                     check equality with 1 (this is for the empty input testcase)
                               where -1 will be pushed by the interpreter
```

If number is not `1` (ie `0` or `-1`[`-1` will be pushed if there is no input]):

```
         <                     start going left
       g0                      gets the first element in stack
     .N                       output it as number and stop program
```

If number is `1`:

```
          v                    gets jumped over by ? since true has been evaluated
           0g1+                gets the first element and adds 1 to it
               1R              rotates stack once clockwise
                  N.          outputs as number and stops program
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, <s>39</s> 36 bytes**

```
#(count(take-while{1 1}(reverse %)))
```

Input as integers `[1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]`, anything other than `1` is falsy. `{1 1}` is a hash-map with key `1` and value `1` which can also used as a function. For example `({1 999} 1)` is `999` (truthy) whereas `({1 999} 0)` is `nil` (falsy).

*Original*, based on booleans:

```
#(count(take-while(fn[i]i)(reverse %)))
```

Amazing how `(fn[i]i)` is shorter than `identity` and also doesn't force you to put a space after `take-while`. Must take a list or vector of booleans, integers can be converted like this: `(map #(= 1 %) [1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1])`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 33 Bytes

```php
<?=strspn(strrev(join($_GET)),1);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9061ab769e556eb927970ba665849af8336f5010)

[strspn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
Length[#/.({___,0,x___/;x==1}:>{x})]&
```

Not the shortest, but short enough where I was proud to submit it :)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 33 bytes

```
,[+++>-[<->-----],]<[>[-<+>]<<]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1pbW9tON9pG104XBGJ1Ym2i7aJ1bbTtYm1sYu30/ttpgwFICAqAMnr/DQ0MDQwMDQE)

Takes input via a string like `101011`, and then outputs via byte value. I've added some code in the footer to add 48 to the value to output a digit.

```
 ,[  Loop over input
   +++>-[<->-----]  Subtract 48 from each value to form a tape of 0s and 1s
 ,]
 <[>[-<+>]<<]   Add up all the trailing ones
 >.             And print the value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```rust
|a|a.iter().rev().take_while(|&&i|i).count()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczBCkIhEIXhfU9hG5kBk1YtinqRuFwsRpJMSceCsme3i5tq0ebnLA5fKpmbDeJiXAB8emJh1zaA3B9i9AMudiW7B21Fq6Ya7ZgSoE50m8rmTOP95DxBldJVh/oYS2DAtpmZnCnxSNc5rJSdPGt8JsWpkPqa/zIg/hjLbnw@neinV3sD)

explanation:

```rust
|a|a.iter().rev().take_while(|&&i|i).count() //anonymous function
|a|a.iter()                                  //iterate over the input
           .rev()                            //reverse the iterator
                 .take_while(|&&i|i)         //take while **self is true
                                    .count() //Count the elements in the iterator
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 18 bytes

```factor
[ [ ] count-tail ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc01ocGefu5WCsWphaWpecmpxXqpFSVFicUIAYWCotSSksqCosy8EgVrLq5qLgUgqFaohdJpcFYJklgJEKahyEFESlBEIOoQutKg6lB1wcRql5aWpOlabIpWiFaIVUjOL80r0S1JzMxRiIVILM1NLFDQg7AXLIDQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.116 bytes

```
Lt@x$
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJMdEB4JCIsIlswLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAxXSJd)

No "group consecutive," unlike most other golfing languages.

```
Lt@x$
    $ # Reverse the list
 t    # Take while
  @x  # The identity function
L     # Return the length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-1`, 3 bytes

```
sP∑
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FkuLAx51TFxSnJRcDBVZcNMjOpYr2gCIDUG0jiEQGuiA-VC2IZQNlgOrgagyhKuB8CAGAgA)

```
s       Find a suffix of the input
 P      that contains only positive integers
  ∑     and sum them.
```

`-1` prints the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `tS`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0UkmwUuyCpaUlaboWi44sXFKclFwM5S5Ya6ijAEQGYNIQIggA)

Or, if you want it flagless:

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġtS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS44sLAleUpyUXAwVWLDWUEcBiAzApCFEEAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ġtS  # Implicit input
ġ    # Group consecutive
 t   # Last item
  S  # Sum
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 7 bytes

```
!?&gGL|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9f0V4t3d2n5v///4b/DYDQEAQB)

### Explanation

```
!?&gGL|  Implicit input from commandline args
!?       If last item on stack is > 0..
  &g     ..Combine all items into single number (1, 1, 0, 1 becomes 1101)
    G    ..Split into digit runs (1101 becomes 11, 0, 1)
     L   ..Pop last item and push length of item (111 becomes 3)
      |  Endif
         Implicit output of last item on stack, either number of trailing ones, or zero
```

Comment: You use 3 chars for the conditional.  Could you maybe multiply by the parity instead?

Comment: @Adám that would still be 3 bytes, 2 bytes to get the parity (`2%`) and one byte to multiply (`*`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 17 bytes

```
v I^: ]|{]1$|{O @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/79MwTPOSiG2pjrWUKWm2l/B4f//akMdBSAyAJOGtQA)

#### Explanation:

```
v I^: ]|{]1$|{O @
v                  Decrease step value to 2
  I                Get input as a number
    : ]|{          Reflect if not EOF
   ^               Increase step value to 3
v                  Decrease to 2 and repeat the loop
         ]         The leftover EOF (-1) is now our counter. Increment it to 0
           $|{     Reflect if the top value is truthy
       |{ 1        Reflect and repeat
         ]         Increment the counter for every truthy value
              O @  Output the final state of the counter
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
Ö⁾ì]*
```

RLE encodes the string, takes the last element, flattens, and multiplies

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr///C0R437Dq@J1fr/38DQwMDA0NAQAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
Ó1*0
ø1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BkQy0DrsM7DP//NzQwMARhIGkIAA) Takes input as a string of `0` and `1`.

### Explanation

```
Ó1*0     Remove all occurences of any number of ones followed by a zero
ø1       Count the number of remaining ones
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 112 bytes

```
1 INPUT B$:T=0:FOR I=LEN(B$) TO 1 STEP -1:C$=MID$(B$,I,1):IF C$="0" THEN 4
2 IF C$="1" THEN T=T+1
3 NEXT
4 PRINT T
```

Just wanted to see if I could do it.

**Explanation**

Input is a string of 1's and 0's. String is traversed from right to left. If the current digit is a 0, bail out and print the total. If the digit is a 1, increment the total and continue to loop.

**Output**

```
? 01100
 0

? 11011
 2

? 11101
 1

? 111111
 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
γθO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZzO/z//4@OBQA)

```
γθO  # full program
  O  # sum of...
 θ   # last...
γ    # group of consecutive equal elements in...
     # implicit input
     # implicit output
```