# Digital Hardness of Integers

Tags: code-golf, number, binary, integer, bitwise

> To find the *digital hardness* of an integer, take its binary representation, and count the number of times both a leading *and* trailing `1` can be removed until it either start or ends with a `0`. The total number of bits removed is its digital hardness.

That's quite a wordy explanation  - so let's break it down with a worked example.

For this example, we'll use the number 3167. In binary, this is:

```
110001011111
```

*(Note that, during the conversion to binary, you should make sure to strip leading zeroes)*

It doesn't start or end with `0`, so we remove 1 pair of bits:

```
1  1000101111  1
```

And another:

```
11  00010111  11
```

But now there is a 0 at the beginning, so we can't remove anymore `1` pairs. In total, 4 bits we removed, and so **4** is the digital hardness of **3167.**

However, for numbers that can be written as **2<sup>n</sup>-1** for positive **n** (i.e. contain only `1` in binary representation), 0 will never be reached, and so all the bits can be removed. This means that the hardness is simply the integer's bit length.

---

### The Challenge

You task is to write a program or function which, given a non-negative integer `n >= 0`, determines its digital hardness.

You can submit a full program which performs I/O, or a function which returns the result. Your submission should work for values of `n` within your language's standard integer range.

---

### Test Cases

Please notify me if any of these are incorrect, or if you'd like to suggest any edge cases to add.

```
0     -> 0
1     -> 1
8     -> 0
23    -> 2
31    -> 5
103   -> 4
127   -> 7
1877  -> 2
2015  -> 10
```

Here's the ungolfed Python solution which I used to generate these test cases (not guaranteed to be bug-less):

```py
def hardness(num) -> int:
    binary = bin(num)[2:]

    if binary.count('0') == 0:
        return num.bit_length()

    revbin = binary[::-1]

    return min(revbin.find('0'), binary.find('0')) * 2
```

Comment: How does `1` return 1 when there is no `0` in it whatsoever? I mean, you can't possibly remove enough 1's from the string to have the it start or end in `0`.

Comment: @busukxuan Read the paragraph just before the "The Challenge" heading: _for numbers that can be written as 2^n-1 (i.e. contain only 1 in binary representation), 0 will never be reached, and so all the bits can be removed. This means that the hardness is simply the integer's bit length._

Comment: What I mean is that maybe defining the hardness as "until not both sides start with 1" might be more appropriate.

Comment: @busukxuan you can think of it as the number of ones each side is padded with, before zeroes are reached.

Comment: To the downvoter who obviously didn't like the edge cases: The _hardness_ is the number of solid (1) bits it is padded with - if the whole thing is solid, then surely it has 100% hardness, its whole bit length?

Comment: @FlipTack I don't want to influence too much, it's your challenge. I initially understood "hardness" as the maximum number of _pairs_ of outer ones that can be removed, one from each side. But you may be right, if a single one remains at the end, perhaps it should be counted in

Comment: Wouldn't the hardness of 103 be 5, as 103 is 1100111 in binary. (theres 5 1's on the end)

Comment: @Cormac read the example - you take the `1`s off in pairs, so with 103 you take 4 off before a zero appears at the beginning.

Comment: i'm a bit confused - of course the binary representation of "0" is "0", but 0 can also be written as 2^n - 1 for n = 0 ?

Comment: @peech Sorry, I meant to include _positive_ for describing n (0 isn't positive). What I meant is numbers where all the binary digits are `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
BµQL××Ṛa\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@90aGugz@Hph6c/3DkrMSb4/9E9h9sfNa1x///fQEfBUEfBQkfByFhHwRjINDQAMgyNzIGEhTmQNDIwNAUA)

#### How it works

```
BµQL××Ṛa\S  Main link. Argument: n

B           Binary; convert n to base 2.
 µ          Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A (array of binary digits)
  Q         Unique; deduplicate the digits.
   L        Length; count the unique digits.
    ×       Multiply each digit by the result.
     ×Ṛ     Multiply the results by reversed A.
       a\   Cumulative reduce by logical AND.
            This zeroes out all elements after the first zero.
         S  Compute the sum of the result.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), <s>76</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>63</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:n>>k&(n&n>>k>n>>k+1)and(n&n+1>0)-~f(n,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#HY3BCsMgEETP7VfMxahkA2paEgLxXywihLSbEnrur9u1l7fDY5mpZX2m1yMnMO2rWzjGvTPctRsbem8T52Z6H50dvsXIp9hajhOMjWEcwRNmQhgJo0TvJPgwCeZJGJy/2@V6eZ8bf4xWt6yhZBF6iJoArcLfSLe19Qc)

#### How it works

This is a recursive solution that takes an input **n** and keeps incrementing **k** – starting at **0**– while both **LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** (bit at index **k** from the right) and **MSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** (bit at index **k** from the left) are set. Once finished, it returns **k** if all of **n**'s bit are set and **2k** if not.

Let's start by rewriting the lambda **f** as a named function **F**, with an auxiliary variable **t**.

```python
def F(n, k = 0):
    t = n >> k
    return t & (n & t > t >> 1) and (n & (n + 1) > 0) + 1 + F(n, k + 1)
```

In each invocation of **F**, we first bit-shift **n** a total of **k** units to the right and store the result in **t**. This way, **LSB<sub>0</sub>(t) = LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)**, so **t** is odd if and only if **LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** is set.

Determining whether **MSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** is set is slightly trickier; this is what `n & t > t >> 1` achieves. To illustrate how it works, let's consider an integer **n = 1αβγδεζη<sub>2</sub>** of bit-length **8** and analyze the function call **F(n, 3)**, i.e., **k = 3**.

We're trying to determine whether **MSB<sub>3</sub>(n) = γ** is set by examining the truth value of the comparison **(n & t > t >> 1) = (1αβγδεζη<sub>2</sub> & 1αβγδ<sub>2</sub> > 1αβγ<sub>2</sub>)**. Let's examine the involved integers.

```python
MSB-index  012k4567

n          1αβγδεζη
t             1αβγδ

t >> 1         1αβγ
```

We claim that **γ = 1** if and only if **n & t > t >> 1**.

- If **γ = 1**, then **n & t** has bit-length **5** while **t >> 1** has bit-length **4**, so **n & t > t >> 1**.

  This proves that **γ = 1** implies **n & t > t >> 1**.
- If **n & t > t >> 1**, there are two options: either **γ = 1** or **γ = 0**. In the first case, there's nothing left to prove.

  In the second case, we have that **αβγδ<sub>2</sub> ≥ n & t > t >> 1 = 1αβγ<sub>2</sub>**.

  Since **αβγδ<sub>2</sub> > 1αβγ<sub>2</sub>**, we must have **MSB<sub>0</sub>(αβγδ<sub>2</sub>) ≥ MSB<sub>0</sub>(1αβγ<sub>2</sub>)**, meaning that **α = 1**.

  This way, **1βγδ<sub>2</sub> > 11βγ<sub>2</sub>**, so we must have **MSB<sub>1</sub>(1βγδ<sub>2</sub>) ≥ MSB<sub>1</sub>(11βγ<sub>2</sub>)**, meaning that **β = 1**.

  In turn, this implies that **11γδ<sub>2</sub> > 111γ<sub>2</sub>**. Remembering that **γ = 0** in the second case, we get the inequality **110δ<sub>2</sub> > 1110<sub>2</sub>**, which is false since **MSB<sub>2</sub>(110δ<sub>2</sub>) = 0 < 1 = MSB<sub>2</sub>(1110<sub>2</sub>)**.

  Thus, only the first case is possible and **n & t > t >> 1** implies **γ = 1**.

Summing up, if both **LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** and **MSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** are set, **t** will be odd and **n & t > t >> 1** will be *True*, so **t & (n & t > t >> 1)** will yield **1**. However, if **LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** or **MSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** is unset (or if both are), **t** will be even or **n & t > t >> 1** will be *False*, so **t & (n & t > t >> 1)** will yield **0**.

Calling **F** with a single argument initializes **k = 0**. While the condition we've discussed earlier holds, the code after `and` is executed, which (among other things) recursively calls **F** with incremented **k**.

Once **LSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** or **MSB<sub>k</sub>(n)** is unset, the condition fails and **F(n, k)** returns **0**. Each of the preceding **k** function calls adds **(n & (n + 1) > 0) + 1** to **F(n, k) = 0**, so **F(n)** returns **((n & (n + 1) > 0) + 1)k**.

Now, if all bits of **n** are equal (i.e., if **n** is either **0** or all of its bits are set), **n + 1** will not have any bits in common with **n**, so **n & (n + 1) = 0** and **F(n)** returns **k**. However, if **n** has both set and unset bits, **n & (n + 1) > 0** and **F(n)** returns **2k**.

Comment: Recursive solutions in Python seems to be scoring really well lately.

Comment: At least compared with iterative solutions, they always have. `input()`, `while`, and `print` are already **17** bytes...

Comment: Yeah, but I find them so much harder to write.

Comment: Fair enough. An straightforward iterative implementation of the same idea would only be 5 bytes longer though. https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioWmdbWvAVZ6RmZOqkaeWZ2eXbQcitA01wRyrbG1bQ66Cosy8EoVsGxsNsAIDzf//jQwMTQE 2 more bytes could be saved with a few tricks. https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY1BDsIgFAXX7SnepgUUI1BNm1K4jKVJQ/I1zV@48uqIcTOZ1UxZ04ZNkppzMD6900NwoBizz@cgqefIV6d69uJ0@ZB/HTsx8rJIjkaV7XmAsBOk0bAak4YbNIaq1lSxbqyYxkpn7F3NbfMviO62CnQg3Ta/e/kC

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
Btv`6L&)}x@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@9UUpZg5qOmWVvhUPj/v5GBoSkA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#U3L471RSlmDmo6ZZW@FQ@N/lf7SBgqGChYKRsYKxoYKhgbGCoZG5gqGFubmCkYGhaSwA).

#### Explanation

The code repeats each binary digit, and counts how many times it is possible to remove two outer ones.

```
B        % Input number (implicit). Horizontal vector of binary digits
tv       % Duplicate and concatenate vertically
`        % Do...while
  6L&)   %   Flatten the array if needed (in column-major order), and split it
         %   into two subarrays: one with the inner entries, and another
         %   with the two outer entries. The latter will be used for deciding
         %   if the loop continues or is exited
}        % Finally (execute before exiting the loop)
  x      %   Delete last subarray of inner entries
  @q     %   Push last iteration index minus 1
         % End (implicit). The next iterarion is executed if the array at the
         % top of the stack is non-empty and only contains nonzero values. 
         % Otherwise the loop is exited, executing the "finally" block first
         % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 82 bytes

I feel like it can still be golfed, but I spent a while trying different methods and this was the shortest.

```python
def f(n):b=bin(n)[2:];x=min(b.find('0'),b[::-1].find('0'));print(x<0)*len(b)or x*2
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VcvBCsIwDAbgu09R8LBmOEkzR0fnfJGxS9kKBa0yPPTtaypuw5zy5c@fptkJJwMY21sfeBnIjF3sHwx7dj5MssACTnYwplLjfoHutfjwlvGKUN5n/obnImJJyUkEwXMU1U3gwUm1UzHb/5RqWEnMWm1schdz/OUlk/RKndlq9tYlVM2PCtMH)

Though this works similarly to the OP's Python program, I created this before the question was posted, after viewing the question in the Sandbox, which did not contain such a program.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 66 bytes

```python
s=bin(input())[2:].split('0')
print len(min(s[-1],s[0]))<<1%len(s)
```

Splits the binary representation of the input into chunks of 1. Counts the number of 1's in the smaller of the first and last chunk, then doubles it, unless there's a single chunk that this would double-count.

Comment: Clever, but still easy to understand. I like it!

Comment: @mbomb007 Take it as a warm up for understanding Dennis's :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>109</s> 106 bytes

```powershell
$a=[convert]::ToString($args[0],2)-split0;(((($b=$a[0].length),$a[-1].length|sort)[0]*2),$b)[$a.count-eq1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#NYlBCoAgEAA/s4eMjCwoKHpF3cSDhVgQWrp16u@2l@Y2Mwn0KFfvHhNQ9f3sJwy7sxnoYKOsVFEzHs9jx2rICFhG0JTLwziLGyvIuPj1jT4go53XdBYmQZervx1ycwmVUmpE230)

Takes input `$args[0]`, uses the .NET call to `convert` it `toString` with base `2` (i.e., make it binary), then `-split`s that string on `0`s, stores that into `$a`. Important to note: the .NET call does not return leading zeros, so the first digit is always a `1`.

There are thus two possibilities -- the binary string is all ones, or there was at least one zero. We differentiate between those with a pseudo-ternary indexed by `$a.count-eq1`. If the binary has at least one zero, the left case, we take the minimum of the length of the first `[0]` string of `1`s and the last `[-1]` string (found by `|sort` and then `[0]`). The shorter of those is the most pairs we could remove, so we multiply that by `2`. Note that if the original binary string ends in a `0`, like for input `8`, then the `[-1].length` will also be `0` (since it's an empty string), which when multiplied by `2` is still `0`.

Otherwise, with the binary string all ones, we take just `$b` (which was previously set to be the length of the first `[0]` string, in this case, the entirety of the binary string).

In either situation, that result is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```js
f=
n=>n.toString(2).replace(/^(1*)(.*(\1))?$/,'$1$3').length
```

```html
<input oninput=o.value=1/this.value?f(+this.value):''><input id=o readonly>
```

Takes the binary and tries to match all `1s` or failing that an equal number of leading and trailing `1s`.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>137</s> <s>132</s> <s>122</s> <s>119</s> <s>117</s> <s>114</s> <s>98</s> <s>94</s> <s>92</s> <s>87</s> 85 Bytes

Time to start golfing B-)

```
i,j;f(n){for(i=1<<30;i&~n;i/=2);for(j=0;n&i;n/=2,i/=4)j+=~n&1?i=0:2;return j-=n<1*j;}
```

Here's the proof

```
main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n", 0, f(0));
  printf("%d %d\n", 1, f(1));
  printf("%d %d\n", 8, f(8));
  printf("%d %d\n", 23, f(23));
  printf("%d %d\n", 31, f(31));
  printf("%d %d\n", 103, f(103));
  printf("%d %d\n", 127, f(127));
  printf("%d %d\n", 1877, f(1877));
  printf("%d %d\n", 2015, f(2015));
  printf("%d %d\n", 3167, f(3167));
}
```

and the output;

```
0 0
1 1
8 0
23 2
31 5
103 4
127 7
1877 2
2015 10
3167 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 48 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
$1o
o1
1
m(+`^1(.*)1$
xx¶$1
x|^1$
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzaWixaWdoGGorRljyKVimM@Vb8hlyJWroZ0QZ6ihp6VpqMJVUXFom4ohV0VNnKHK//@GFubmAA)

#### Explanation:

```
.+              # Convert to unary
$*
+`(1+)\1        # Convert to binary (but with `o` instead of `0` -- it's shorter)
$1o
o1
1
m(+`^1(.*)1$    # Replace pairs of surrounding ones with `xx`
xx¶$1
x|^1$,          # Count x's, including the possibility of a single remaining `1`
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 133 bytes

Function that returns hardness. Takes integer from argument.

```
int h(int b){var n=Convert.ToString(b,2);for(b=0;;){if(n[0]+n[n.Length-1]==98)n=n.Substring(1,n.Length-2);else break;b+=2;}return b;}
```

Well, today I found out `'1' + '1' = 98` in C#.

Comment: That's because `'1'` is the ASCII char 49, and 49 + 49 = 98.

Comment: I literally spent 10 minutes figuring out why my `1 + 1 = 2` didn't work. @FlipTack

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 85 bytes

Saved two bytes due to @FlipTack pointing out a useless declaration.

Call `f()` with the number to test, the output is returned from the function.

```
t,h;f(l){for(t=l;t&&~t&1<<30;t*=2);for(h=0;t&1<<30&&l&1;t*=2,l/=2)++h;return h<<!!l;}
```

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/SK3r6x).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Eo2
BµŒg.ịṂS×Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AT0Awv//RW8yCkLCtcWSZy7hu4vhuYJTw5fDh//Dh@KCrFn//zAsMSw4LDIzLDMxLDEwMywxMjcsMTg3NywyMDE1)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```js
f=(n,m=1<<30)=>m>n?f(n,m/2):m>1?n&m&&n&1&&2+f(n/2,m/4):n&1
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,m=1<<30)=>m>n?f(n,m/2):m>1?n&m&&n&1&&2+f(n/2,m/4):n&1

console.log(
  [0, 1, 8, 23, 31, 103, 127, 1877, 2015].map(
    n => n + ' -> ' + f(n)
  ).join('\n')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>181</s> <s>156</s> 150 bytes

```java
n->{int i=0;String s=n.toString(n,2);if(s.matches("1*"))i=s.length();else for(;!s.matches("(.*0)|(0.*)");s=s.substring(1,s.length()-1))i+=2;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TZBNb4MwDIbP8Cs8Tkk/IkI1tVLG7pM27dBj1UOggUaCgOJQbWL89iyITuvRr/08st0PRaNLKBuJCB9SGxjjCJ10IdTGKVvJUsG7bIuLhHGOwA6GvIVWrSx8UQGTiKM46hfRHb11@gJt0JGjs9rUpzNIWyOF8a6qIAdvtq/jbNR5KpY5wNww1y0FMZuMCl0RZK105VUhSfgqoVTnyBplanclVKgGFVSdJeLpYY6wVUp/SMpWNKECA4BDgYuWb/7xLQ@6dZ4Jq9xgDWgx@SgKF0Wz8m85/TJvf4eEXq/p8Rudalk3ONYHqWsMqdjDZ9hNNoP6rMgMnvSZUhqkUzx5n3ruDz7b@R33PN15nu09P@z3Pkv58y8)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>63</s> 56 bytes

```
(2-Min[l=#~IntegerDigits~2])Min[Tr/@Split[l][[{1,-1}]]]&
```

**Explanation**

```
l=#~IntegerDigits~2
```

Generate the base-2 representation of the input, wrapped with a `List`. Store that in `l`

```
(2-Min[...])
```

If the min element of `l` is 1, output 1. If not, output 2. Multiply this by...

```
Split[l]
```

Split `l` into runs.

```
... [[{1,-1}]]
```

Take the first and the last element.

```
Tr/@ ...
```

Take the total of both.

```
Min[ ... ]
```

Find the smaller between the two.

(Multiply the first result (1 or 2) with this result).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
?*FJjQ2lJyhSxR0_BJ
```

A program that takes input of an integer and prints the result.

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=pQp%22+-%3E+%22%0A%3F%2aFJjQ2lJyhSxR0_BJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A8%0A23%0A31%0A103%0A127%0A1877%0A2015&debug=0) (First line for formatting)

**How it works**

```
?*FJjQ2lJyhSxR0_BJ  Program. Input: Q
?                   If
  F                 reducing
    jQ2             the binary representation of Q as a list
   J                (store in J)
 *                  by multiplication is truthy:
       lJ            Yield len(J)
                    Else:
          hS         Yield the minimum
            xR0      of the first index of zero
               _BJ   in J and its reverse
         y           * 2
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
 @(n)cummin(d=dec2bin(n)-48)*cummin(flip(d))'*2^!all(d)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#IAfFY)

Explanation:

```
d=dec2bin(n)-48
```

binary representation of `n`

```
cumd= cummin(d);
cumfd = cummin(flip(d));
```

Take cumulative min of `d`  and cumulative min of flipped `d`

```
res = cumd * cumfd ';
```

do matrix multiplication

```
out = res*2^!all(d)
```

multiply with 2 if all of digits is 1;

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>83</s> 74 bytes

3+6 bytes saved by Jörg

```php
<?=(~$s=decbin($argn))[$a=strspn($s,1)]?min($a,strspn(strrev($s),1))*2:$a;
```

takes input from STDIN; run with `-nR`.

**breakdown**

```
<?=                     # print ...
(~
    $s=decbin($argn)        # $s = binary representation of input
)[
    $a=strspn($s,1)         # $a = number of leading `1`s
]                           # if $s has more than $a digits,
?   min($a,                     # 2. minimum of $a and
        strspn(strrev($s),1)    # 1. number of trailing `1`s
    )*2                         # 3. *2
:   $a                      # else $a (==strlen)
```

Comment: `<?=~($s=decbin($argn))[$a=strspn($s,1)]?2*min($a,strspn(strrev($s),1)):$a;`

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 26 bytes

```
+/∘(∧\≢↑(∊⊢(,∧∧)¨⌽))2⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

Test cases:

```
      ( +/∘(∧\≢↑(∊⊢(,∧∧)¨⌽))2⊥⍣¯1⊢ ) ¨ 0 1 8 23 31 103 127 1877 2015    
0 1 0 2 5 4 7 2 10
```

Explanation:

```
+/∘(∧\≢↑(∊⊢(,∧∧)¨⌽))2⊥⍣¯1⊢

                         ⊢   input
                    2⊥⍣¯1    convert to binary representation
   (               )
        (  ⊢    ¨⌽)          for each bit and its matching bit on the other side
            (  ∧)               take the logical and of both bits,
             ,                  make a list of both bits,
              ∧                 then take the and of the list and the and
         ∊                   flatten the resulting array
      ≢↑                     take only the first N bits, where N is the
                                length of the original list of bits
    ∧\                       take a running logical and (leaving only the
                                starting ones)
+/∘                          sum those
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 22 bytes

```
(#<.2*(<.&(#.~)|.))@#:
```

This is based on the neat trick learned from this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98730/count-trailing-truths).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#BcHRCYAwDAXAf6d4WJCkSEhSpKVUcBex@OcC4ur1bnTsFRSaeKQmCwX5@BXmI9TpOu8HtEqflaEwFHhCMpgmmGdYyRmuto3xAw)

### Explanation

```
(#<.2*(<.&(#.~)|.))@#:  Input: integer n
                    #:  Binary digits of n
(                 )@    Operate on those digits D
               |.         Reverse D
       <.                 Take the minimum of
         &(#.~)           the "trailing truths" of D and reverse(D)
    2*                    Multiply by 2
 #                        The length of D
  <.                      Minimum of length and the previous result
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 Bytes

```
f=x=>(y=x.toString(2),y.match(/^1*$/)?y:([s,e]=y.match(/^1*|1*$/g),s<e?s:e)).length
```

Ungolfed:

```
function f(n) {
    var binStr = n.toString(2);
    if(binStr.match(/^1*$/)) {
        // If binary representation is all 1s, return length of binary
        return binStr.length;
    } else {
        // Grab the starting and ending 1s in the binary representation
        var [start1s, end1s] = binStr.match(/^1*|1*$/g);
        var startHardness = start1s.length;
        var endHardness = end1s.length;
        return Math.min(startHardness, endHardness);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>94</s> 92 bytes

```haskell
b 0=[]
b n=mod n 2:b(div n 2)
h n|(c,_:_)<-span(>0)$zipWith(*)n$reverse n=c++c|1<3=n
sum.h.b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcsxDoMgFADQvaf4AwPUlqBNFyu9RIcOTWMESWDgSwA1Md6d2u0tzw8OQUKY8ytH4JDstAKBNHtuuTrUiPpeFAj5@T4UoPTTCAhNq@jolr/YyQLuVF/6tmfdNYUB6VMwsrnwdtnSM0MSzWJiMkfXVaX3urtJLOUH) Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> sum.h.b $ 3167
4
```

**Explanation:**
`b` converts a number to binary and returns a list of zero and ones with the least significant bit first. In `h`, this list is reversed and element-wise multiplied with the original list, then `span(>0)` splits after the initial `1`s:

```haskell
       b 3167 = [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1] = n
    reverse n = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1] = m
zipWith(*)n m = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] = z
   span(>0) z = ([1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1])
```

The resulting tuple is pattern matched with `(c,_:_)` where `_:_` matches any non-empty list, so `c = [1,1]`. Because the bytes are removed at front and back, `c++c = [1,1,1,1]` is returned and finally summed up to yield the *digital hardness*.

If the second list of the tuple is empty, then the binary representation contains ones only, and the number of ones is the digital hardness. With the pattern matching failed `h` returns just `n`, which is again summed up.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
(h=0;#~IntegerDigits~2//.{{1,m___,1}:>(h+=2;{m}),{1}:>h++};h)&
```

Pure function where `#` represents the first argument.

`(h=0;...;h)&` sets `h=0`, does a bunch of stuff `...`, then returns `h` (the hardness). Let's look at the bunch of stuff:

```
#~IntegerDigits~2                                     Binary representation of the input
                 //.                                  Apply the following list of rules repeatedly until there is no change
                    {                                 Start of the list of rules
                     {1,m___,1}                       If you see a list starting and ending with 1 with the sequence m (possibly empty) in between
                               :>(h+=2;{m}),            replace it with just {m} after incrementing h twice.
                                            {1}       If you see the singleton list {1}
                                               :>h++    replace it with h, then increment h.
                                                    } End of the list of rules
```

Thanks to Greg Martin for introducing me to [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105426/61980).

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 61 bytes

```perl
sub f{$_=sprintf('%b',pop);length(/0/?/^(1+).*\1$/&&$1x2:$_)}
```

The heart of this is the regex `/^(1+).*\1$/` where 2 times the length of `$1` is the answer.  Rest of the code is overhead and dealing with the all 1's special case.

Comment: You can omit the parenthesis around `sprintf` arguments. Also, using `-p` flag will allow you to write a full program that will be shorter than your function as you'll be able to omit `sub f{...}` (instead you'll have to end with `$_=...` but that's still a 4 bytes improvement). Finally, instead of your `length(...)`, you can do `/0/&&s/^(1+).*\1$/$1$1/;$_=y///c`. This should get you to 51 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 65 Bytes

```php
<?=strlen(preg_filter('#^(1*)(.*(\1))?$#',"$1$3",decbin($argn)));
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36911bed84d77ca7eeaa4df7270accd6bba87301)

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 14 bytes

```
ri2b_0#\W%0#e<
```

Explanation:

```
ri e# Read integer:      | 3167
2b e# Convert to binary: | [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
_  e# Duplicate:         | [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1] [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
0# e# Index of first 0:  | [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1] 2
\  e# Swap:              | 2 [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
W% e# Reverse:           | 2 [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
0# e# Index of first 0:  | 2 5
e< e# Minimum:           | 2
```