# Alternating bit smearing

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary, bitwise

### Introduction

This challenge requires you to set the trailing zeros of an integers binary representation to `010101…`, this is best explained with an example:

Given the integer `400`, the first step is to convert it to binary:

```
110010000
```

As we can see the fifth bit is the least significant `1` bit, so starting from there we replace the lower zeros by `0101`:

```
110010101
```

Finally we convert that back to decimal: `405`

### Challenge

Given a positive integer return/output the corresponding resulting value of the above defined process.

### Rules

- This sequence is only defined for integers with at least one `1` bit, so the input will always be ≥ 1
- You may take input as a string, list of digits (decimal) instead
- You don't have to handle invalid inputs

### Testcases

Here are some more testcases with the intermediary steps (you don't have to print/return these):

```
In -> … -> … -> Out
1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1
2 -> 10 -> 10 -> 2
3 -> 11 -> 11 -> 3
4 -> 100 -> 101 -> 5
24 -> 11000 -> 11010 -> 26
29 -> 11101 -> 11101 -> 29
32 -> 100000 -> 101010 -> 42
192 -> 11000000 -> 11010101 -> 213
400 -> 110010000 -> 110010101 -> 405
298 -> 100101010 -> 100101010 -> 298
```

Comment: Can we assume a 32-bit integer?

Comment: @Arnauld: Sure!

Comment: Some golfing idea: If `n` is the maximal power of 2 that divides the input, then the answer is simply `(input) + ceil((2^n - 2)/3)`

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n&-n)//3+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoMwFET3OcXHRTF0RE1cVEEvYrtQ2tBA/YrJpqdPjSUwMLyZt339e2UdTH8Pn2mZnxNxl/OlYFmW@srBv5x31NNYQ0GjgTrSQivUrUJTVQfdHkKYdafokuWzXSdo2y37PBIoK4YMZE6SMn2z5f@ShDgkSYYf)

### Explanation

Take `192` as an example. Its binary form is `11000000`, and we need to convert it to `11010101`.

We note that we need to add `10101` to the number. This is a geometric series (`4^0 + 4^1 + 4^2`), which has a closed form as `(4^3-1)/(4-1)`. This is the same as `4^3//3` where `//` denotes integer division.

If it were `101010`, then it would still be a geometric series (`2×4^0 + 2×4^1 + 2×4^2`), which is `2×4^3//3` for the reasons above.

Anyway, `4^3` and `2×4^3` would just be the least significant bit, which we obtain by `n&-n`:

We notice that the complement of `n` is `00111111`. If we add one, it becomes `01000000`, and it only overlaps with `n=11000000` at the least significant digit. Note that "complement and add one" is just negation.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder nice sportsmanship

Comment: Possibly `lambda n:(n&-n)//3+n` works too? Passes [all the sample test cases](https://tio.run/##XYvLCoMwEEX38xWDi2J0JDG6qEL6I20XhlYrtKNoNv36NL42hYHhnHvv@HWvgQvfmpt/Nx/7aJDrmE8ZCymLlH1n/nSS6JBIuVHKAO45uxkNXnPSVFBJOlxFhaa80lQqFeh8B7ChowDaYcJlgj2vf64Bx6lnFy9EGGWXiLBdSYgjsz1v5igs4iiFlk1Nt5ExuwbYp2gM5kr4Hw), but according to my intuition it shouldn't be valid, right?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder it is indeed valid.

Comment: Why not use Python 2 to save a byte? [TIO](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoMwFET3OcXHRTF0pPrjogr2Im0XShsaaL9isunpU2MJDAxv5i3f8JqFox1u8T1@psdI0pdyqESfzFFiePrgaaBrA4ZBC97SwTCajtHW9Ubnu1J2Xim55GRv3ytaViehTAQqqksBsjtpnb/JyX/JQhqypOMP "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @FlipTack I hate python 2

Comment: @LeakyNun haha, who doesn't

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
&N:3+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/Nz8pY@3@0oY6RjrGOiY4REFnqGBvpGFoa6ZgYGAB5FjrGQLaRsYVF7OH2R01rIv8DAA)

This time a port of [Leaky Nun's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151543/59487) (at least I helped him golf it down a bit :P)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
^N+4:6ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/OT9vEyuzhroX/ow11jHSMdUx0jIDIUsfYSMfQ0kjHxMAAyLPQMbY0ij3c/qhpTeR/AA)

Uses [JungHwan Min's fantastic approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151544/59487), with indirect help from [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender).

Comment: Dennis posted, then deleted, a very similar 5-byte solution _just_ after you made that edit. Something like `&N:3|`. Congratulations; you beat Dennis in Jelly! (But not quite out-golfed.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I really didn't do much, apart from suggesting a small golf to Leaky's approach and then porting it. But eh :-)

Comment: This is the first ASCII-only Jelly answer I've ever seen.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>36</s> <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

<sup>-8 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder and -2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder</sup>

```
#+⌊(#~BitAnd~-#)/3⌋&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1n7UU@XhnKdU2aJY15Kna6ypr7xo55utf8BRZl5JQ5aafoO1VxchjoKRjoKxjoKJkAGCFsCeUARQ0sgYWJgABKx4OKq/Q8A)

We only need to find the number of the trailing zeroes in the input, and find the number with alternating `0`s and `1`s with length one less than that, and add it to the input.

So, `400 -> 11001000 -> 110010000 + 0000 -> 110010101 + 101 -> 405`

The explicit formula for `n`th number with alternating `1`s and `0`s was given in [A000975](http://oeis.org/A000975) on OEIS. We can use the `n`th number since no two different numbers can the same length in binary and have alternating digits.

Comment: `2^#~IntegerExponent~2` is `(BitXor[#,#-1]+1)/2`

Comment: @MartinEnder wow! And then I can just combine the fractions to reduce more bytes

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1n7UU@XhnKdU2aJY15Kna6ypr7xo55utf8BRZl5JQ5aafoO1VxchjoKRjoKxjoKJkAGCFsCeUARQ0sgYWJgABKx4OKq/Q8A). You can use `#+⌊(#~BitAnd~-#)/3⌋&` instead.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder edited :)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sub><s>19</s></sub> 18 bytes

```
+(2|-.i.@#.-.)&.#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT1vDqCZTzyFTT83QoUZPU01P2ep/anJGvkKaQmpZalGlgqGCkYKxgomCERBZKhgbKRhaGimYGBgAeRb/AQ)

## Quick Explanation

This is an old answer, but it is very similar in nature to the current one, it just counts the trailing zeroes differently. See the comments for a link explaining how it works.

```
+(2|i.@i.&1@|.)&.#:
                 #:  Convert to binary list
       i.&1@|.       Index of last 1 from right
            |.         Reverse
       i.&1            Index of first 1
    i.               Range [0, index of last 1 from right)
  2|                 That range mod 2
               &.    Convert back to decimal number
+                    Add to the input
```

#### Other Answers:

Previous answer (19 bytes).

```
+(2|i.@i.&1@|.)&.#:
```

Longer than it should be because `\` goes right-to-left.

```
+(2|#*-.#.-.)\&.(|.@#:)
```

Comment: 18 bytes ``+(2|-.i.@#.-.)&.#:``

Comment: @miles mind explaining what's going on with the base conversion there? I'm guessing it's got something to do with the zeroes but I'm not sure.

Comment: ``#.~`` [counts the number of trailing truths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98730/count-trailing-truths), so what we need is ```#.~ -. #:``` to count the number of trailing zeroes

Comment: @miles Ah! That’s very, very clever.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
!n=n|n&-n÷3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fMc82ryZPTTfv8Hbj/2n5RQp5Cpl5ChqGOgpGOgrGOgomQAYIWwJ5QBFDSyBhYmAAErHQ5OJ0KCjKzCtJ01BSNS5V0LVTAFIxeUo6Cnk6Cop5mlypeSn/AQ)

Comment: This looks like an efficient method, can you explain the operator precedence? For example, I can't tell whether it's evaluated as `((!n=(n|n))&-n)/3`, or `!n=(((n|n)&(-n))/3)`, etc.

Comment: In Julia, bitwise operators have the same precedences as their arithmetic counterparts, so `|` is like `+` and `&` is like `*`. Therefore, `n|n&-n÷3` is parsed as `n | ((n&-n) ÷3)`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

Takes input as a 32-bit integer.

```js
n=>n|((n&=-n)&(m=0xAAAAAAAA)?m:m/2)&--n
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>n|((n&=-n)&(m=0xAAAAAAAA)?m:m/2)&--n

console.log(f(1))   // 1 -> 1 -> 1
console.log(f(2))   // 10 -> 10 -> 2
console.log(f(3))   // 11 -> 11 -> 3
console.log(f(4))   // 100 -> 101 -> 5
console.log(f(24))  // 11000 -> 11010 -> 26
console.log(f(29))  // 11101 -> 11101 -> 29
console.log(f(32))  // 100000 -> 101010 -> 42
console.log(f(192)) // 11000000 -> 11010101 -> 213
console.log(f(400)) // 110010000 -> 110010101 -> 405
console.log(f(298)) // 100101010 -> 100101010 -> 298
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>71</s> 58 bytes

*thanks to NofP for -6 bytes*

```r
function(n){n=n%/%(x=2^(0:31))%%2
n[!cumsum(n)]=1:0
n%*%x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPszrPNk9VX1WjwtYoTsPAythQU1NV1YgrL1oxuTS3uDQXqCTW1tDKgCtPVUu1ovZ/moahpZHmfwA)

Assumes input is a 32-bit integer. R only has signed 32-bit integers (casting to `double` when an integer overflows) anyway and no 64-bit or unsigned ints.

Comment: You can convert the `which.max(n):1-1` to `!cumsum(n)` to get a [65 bytes solution](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPszrPNk9VX1WjwtYoTsPAythQU1NV1YgrL1oxuTS3uDQXqCTW1tDKgCtPVUsVpqT2f5qGoaWR5n8A)

Comment: @NofP thanks! That's a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> <s>8</s> 5 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to *Mr. Xcoder* and [JungHwan Min's neat formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151544/47066)
Saved another 3 thanks to *Mr. Xcoder*

```
(&3÷+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fQ8348Hbt//8NLY0A)

**Explanation**

```
(      # negate input
 &     # AND with input
  3÷   # integer divide by 3
    +  # add to input
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that porting the Mathematica answer gives you [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJs5Y10z/8Drt//9NDAwA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Ooh, that's a neat formula.

Comment: Does 05ab1e have bitwise AND? If so, `(<bitwise and here>3÷+` should work for ~5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 120 bytes

```
>+<[[>-]++>[[>]>]<[>+>]<[<]>-]>[-<+>[-<[<]<]>]>[>]<[>+<[->+<]<[->+<]<]>>[<]+>[-[-<[->+<<+>]>[-<+>]]<[->++<]<[->+<]>>>]<<
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb8IwDL3nV/g4qXQa0w6bGvk3cI9yCI2BiJKgJDC2P8/sfogdNh9i2X5@fq67zS7E3aU/3lcGm9FMq9vZ0Gq9pMV0axFXVt@x0cZga5sG2VvGMUxebTmLTNHIwyEnOJ4A2rT82MUxFwMEKFDJcdfcbCfUA40oYu5ctVptcoi1gIOehgGubrgQPFV3pAi7nE5AJQ0u7gtsd3B2e1IGWR7zjwugMlpGIUsVz2GLBrrPQxhoZqNbKLUoAPi9PnQnHsJz1y9SYmWt7C2im0n2GGkxC50P1@AXxu3X3CUrcC3FCpHIQz2EMi4ixWWU0ZNHwTrv4e0daoJMJ76XpzwRjVsIotSUiZnoX8SeZNytTmqkqLXi2yj@vtDRUGhWk2De8ZtyGknwD1HKqu4sVwAXPfQDuQzk@gOMSvxDBoTIwZVyIR71LOfj/2f98foD)

Starts with the value in the current cell and ends on the cell with the output value. Obviously won't work on numbers above 255 as that's the cell limit for typical brainfuck, but will work if you assume infinite cell size.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval((bin(n).rstrip("0")+"01"*n)[:len(bin(n))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrNCoMwEATgu0@x5JRttyU/HqpgX8R6iFRpIF0lCYU@fapSGBg@ZtZvfi1sy9w9SnDv8emA2@njgpSjZ8l4jSlHv0qhBJ6F0uLE2Ldh4v@OA5Y8pZygg16TIUs1mS0NWUO6MVQrtek2VNW8RNi/4Pno1FawRs9Z7iIQl7sgmA8hlh8)

Not really happy with this yet, but I really didn't want to use the formula... -2 thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod). -1 thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).

Comment: `eval(...)` instead of `int(...,2)` could save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 168 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$a=($c=[convert])::ToString($n,2);if(($x=[regex]::Match($a,'0+$').index)-gt0){$c::ToInt32(-join($a[0..($x-1)]+($a[$x..$a.length]|%{(0,1)[$i++%2]})),2)}else{$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BDoIwFEQv84n9KTSAKzEcwIUr3TVdNPiFmlpIaZQEOXsty8m8eTONX/LzQNbGOGmv3wwcgm4ZdK3sRvchHxQ2zX28BW9cn@q8xrN5MgZLKz31tKimuerQDQx0fig5HFAY96AFiz6UuEK3zy8uHGtWvEbjEidLIZKgqFDxPcIiBGhhyfVhUL9sZWVeoQTDeVarDTGdbmRnWsFtMcbqVP8B)

Ouch. Conversion to/from binary and array slicing are not really PowerShell's strong suits.

Takes input `$n` as a number. We immediately `convert` that to binary base `2` and store that into `$a`. Next we have an if/else construct. The if clause tests whether a `regex` `Match` against 1 or more `0`s at the end of the string (`'0+$'`) has its `index` at a location greater than `0` (i.e., the start of the binary string). If it does, we have something to work with, `else` we just output the number.

Inside the `if`, we slice of the `x`th first digits, and array-concatenate `+` those with the remaining digits. However, for the remaining digits, we loop through them and select either a `0` or `1` to be output instead, using `$i++%2` to choose. This gets us the `010101...` pattern instead of `0`s at the end. We then `-join` that back together into a string, and `$c`onvert it back into an `Int32` from base `2`.

In either situation, the number is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 56 bytes

```
i,k;f(n){for(k=i=1;n>>i<<i==n;k+=++i&1)k*=2;return n|k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BCsIwEAXQfU8RCkpiKzS1C8t0ehI3Eo0MwVFCXdWePUa3Os7yP/h/3PbiXEpUB/CazexvUQcktMDjSMNAiAyhwqqitTVhgy3E8/SIrPgZYEnEk7oeibUp5kLlu8cceV2uTgcua@W1NQZ@SyvKTpRObvtDvbwkP2F72bqm@bYs6rO2f9uSXg)

## C (gcc), 50 bytes

```
i,k;f(n){for(k=i=1;n>>i<<i==n;k+=++i&1)k*=2;k|=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BCsIwEAXQfU8RCkpiKjS1C0s6PUk3EokMg1Mp7mrPHqNbO87yP/h/wvEWQkpYkY@azRKnWRMgOM/DgH2PAOzJgrW4d4YO0Hh65WhNyE91vyBrUyyFyveYcxR1ubuOXFYqameM35ZGlJMordz2hzp5SX7CdbK1df1rWdR37fyxNb0B)

**<s>51</s>  48 bytes using [Arnauld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151547/61405):**

*Thanks to @l4m2 for saving three bytes!*

```
m;f(n){return n|((n&-n)&(m=-1u/3*2)?m:m/2)&n-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BCsIwEAXQfU8xFAwzYmiTdmEN4kXcSDTSRQYJ7ar27DG61XGW/8H/4/Xd@5yjC8i0pNs0JwZ@IrLSTArjUZu56baWTvEQG0uKtXFrHnmCeBkZqVoqKPdIJQpYb65nrncQ0BC532JF6UTp5bY/NMhL8hNmkK1v228rAp@1/dvW/AI)

**43 with gcc:**

```
m;f(n){m=n|((n&-n)&(m=-1u/3*2)?m:m/2)&n-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/XOk0jT7M61zavRkMjT003T1NNI9dW17BU31jLSNM@1ypX30hTLU/X0Lr2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNZcCEBQUAYXSNJRUU2LylHQU0jQMNTWtscsY4ZQxxiljgts0PFKWuG3C7QhDS9xyJgYGmHJAGQWwbRYgudr/AA)

Comment: `0xAAAAAAAA` => `-1u/3*2`

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$n+(($x=$n-band-$n)-$x%3)/3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPW0NDpcJWJU83KTEvRRcopKtSoWqsqW/8//9/Q0sjAA) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##DcjRCoIwFIDh@57iIEfY8Izm5kVe2ItEyCpXgh1lGgnms6/Bf/P90/jtwvzqhiH6D9@XfmTwW5xccG@BLJELIXBtkNXN8UOlpXDNrTzauB/Qhed80ddfvmXYgjpDBgUID9jKPcaSDFmqyKRqsobK2lClddLpDw)

Port of Leaky Nun's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151543/42963).

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun*

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 43 bytes

```
p←+/^\⌽~n←((⌊1+2⍟n)⍴2)⊤n←⎕⋄2⊥((-p)↓n),p⍴0 1
```

Prompts for screen input

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 47 bytes

```php
<?php function b($a){echo(int)(($a&-$a)/3)+$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhrTQvuSQzP08hSUMlUbM6NTkjXyMzr0RTA8hV0wUK6RtraqskWtf@T9IwMTDQtP4PAA)

Really just another port of @Leaky Nun's solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf'%b',<>;1while s/00(0*)$/01$1/;say oct"0b$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRNXTVJXcfGztqwPCMzJ1WhWN/AQMNAS1NF38BQxVDfujixUiE/uUTJIEklXun/f5N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 18 bytes

A port of Leaky Nun's approach

```rust
|n:i32|(n&-n)/3+n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQ5qSUKFQq2Cv9r8qwyjY1qNPLUdPM09Y2186z/g@QLijLzSnLyFDWUqmuVdBQqNAwtjTQ1rblq/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 15 bytes

Another port of Leaky Nun's approach.

```ruby
->k{(k&-k)/3+k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NCoMwEITv@xRTpZJQtJp4qIX6JIVi/QGJVdGEUsRnT5N2mMPOt8syi3l@bGfGGjfcbVyqjakoVvwsT2q3ul316jbHN8sgIJFDOBeQAlkhkKepSxdOv8PkVc0HFl319Og5UTct8Bz9iP@jZiI4zcbNQbh5uCMuEW6@QVJXw8A85HtA7diQ/QI)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 24 bytes

A port of JungHwan Min's Mathmatica  answer

```
$0=int(and($0,-$0)/3+$0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcA2M69EIzEvRUPFQEdXxUBT31gbSP7/b2hpBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 13 bytes

```
n=>(n&-n)/3|n
```

```js
f = 
n=>(n&-n)/3|n
;
console.log (f(8));
console.log (f(243));
console.log (f(1048576));
console.log (f(33554432));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

A port of Leaky Nun's approach.

```
n->n+bitand(n,-n)\3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y5POymzJDEvRSNPRzdPM8b4f0FRZl6JRpqGoaWRpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 39 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.875 bytes

```
N⋏3ḭ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiTuKLjzPhuK0rIiwiIiwiNDAwIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
011000110010011000101101101111111101001
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
BŒgṪµ2Ḷṁ×CḄ+³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//QsWSZ@G5qsK1MuG4tuG5gcOXQ@G4hCvCs////zM5Mg)

**Explanation**

Take 24 as an example input.

```
BŒgṪµ2Ḷṁ×CḄ+³
B                Binary representation of the input → 11000
 Œg              Group runs of equal length → [[1,1],[0,0,0]]
   Ṫ             Tail → [0,0,0]
    µ            New monadic link
     2Ḷ          [0,1] constant
       ṁ         Mold [0,1] to the shape of [0,0,0] → [0,1,0]
        ×        Multiply [0,1,0] by...
         C       1-[0,0,0]. If last bit(s) of the original input are 1 this will add nothing to the original input
          Ḅ      Convert to decimal from binary → 2
           +³    Add this with the original input → 26
```