# CSI: Minecraft Items

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, game, integer

[Minecraft 1.12](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.12) will be released tomorrow, so let's celebrate!

Write code that takes in a non-negative integer N which represents the number of items of something in [Minecraft](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft). Output it in a way more helpful to players, giving the number of chests, stacks, and items N is equivalent to. Use the format

```
XcYsZi
```

where

- `X` is the number of chests you can completely fill with N items,
- `Y` is the number of stacks you can fill with the items remaining after filling chests,
- `Z` if the number of items remaining after filling chests and stacks.

Note that:

- 64 items fit in a stack. (We'll ignore items that stack to 16 or don't stack.)
- 27 stacks fit in a chest. (These are single chests, not double chests.)

So it would never make sense if `Y` is more than 26 or if `Z` is more than 63.

A caveat with the format is that if there is zero of something, that term is not printed.

- So, for example, if `Y` were zero and `X` and `Z` nonzero, the format would look like `XcZi`.
- Likewise if `Y` and `Z` were zero and `X` nonzero, the format would be `Xc`.
- **The exception here is when N is zero.** Then `0i` is the output rather than an empty string.

You can assume all N items are of the same type, hence all stackable.

You may not output a list or tuple of three numbers. You must give a string with the exact "csi" notation, in that order, with no spaces or commas.

For reference, here's a chest completely filled with stacks of items:

[image: Minecraft single chest filled with 27 stacks of diamonds]

## Testcases

```
in -> out
0 -> 0i
1 -> 1i
2 -> 2i
62 -> 62i
63 -> 63i
64 -> 1s
65 -> 1s1i
66 -> 1s2i
127 -> 1s63i
128 -> 2s
129 -> 2s1i
200 -> 3s8i
512 -> 8s
1337 -> 20s57i
1664 -> 26s
1727 -> 26s63i
1728 -> 1c
1729 -> 1c1i
1791 -> 1c63i
1792 -> 1c1s
1793 -> 1c1s1i
4096 -> 2c10s
5183 -> 2c26s63i
5184 -> 3c
5200 -> 3c16i
9999 -> 5c21s15i
385026 -> 222c22s2i
1000000000 -> 578703c19s
```

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79609/48934)

Comment: ok apparently this is a crime scene investigation

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37905/8478)

Comment: @Okx with all the spinoffs that wouldn't be surprising.  Now we need a challenge with drawing a chalk outline -- of a creeper perhaps

Comment: Mulling it over now, but I don't think this challenge can be done *in* Minecraft. No way to concatenate the output string. Maybe I could display the result as an actual pile of chests, blocks, and items :)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>26</s>  24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
d64d1¦27Fża¥“csi”Fḟ0ȯ⁾0i
```

A full program taking the number and printing the result.
It does seem too long to me...

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//ZDY0ZDHCpjI3RsW8YcKl4oCcY3Np4oCdRuG4nzDIr@KBvjBp////MTcyOQ)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsIwDEWvwgGMZDuJ0yyMvQNCDIgytOrGxFZYuASICSYkVoaKoagS1yAXCc7Al/8f7PfdbNp2l1IltqLhxr4c@9Vwjd1pva1jdy6/zwt@HnH/wjqN/fsYD/dGrcBkOpsoMU9pgUDAIDoGxII4EAFiry7UARgRHDGQMboUZcjns893rwD5QDk4hwGLQbRQmBwWXO4HFZjCIetv/Gv5Aw).

#### How?

*updating...*

```
d64d1¦27Fża¥“csi”Fḟ0ȯ⁾0i - Main link: number n
 64                      - literal 64
d                        - divmod (whole divisions and remainder)
      27                 - literal 27
    1¦                   - apply to index 1 (the whole division from above)
   d                     - divmod
        F                - flatten into a single list (of three items i.e. [(n/64)/27, (n/64)%27, n%64]
            “csi”        - literal ['c','s','i']
           ¥             - last two links as a dyad:
         ż               -   zip
          a              -   logical and (any 0s in the divmod result become [0,0], others become [integer, character]
                 F       - flatten (from list of three lists to one list)
                  ḟ0     - filter discard zeros
                     ⁾0i - literal ['0','i']
                    ȯ    - logical or (non-vectorising)
                         - implicit print (smashed together representation, so [578703,'c',19,'i'] prints as 578703c19i)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 41 bytes

```
.+
$*i
i{64}
s
s{27}
c
(.)\1*
$.&$1
^$
0i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUtJDsIwDLzPOwpCIFWxnTjJC/gFAkUceuFAuJW@PbVrzSJ5Zr7v3/J5jdPl/hzzDdMVtGrc0NFXzhsaHtOfLJjPC/rhHe3wNkYAgaEGgUZogiqIs7EYKzgEJGKQiD3VOpQ9zp5nK1Cu5MIughiq2qCIS0TyfbWDlBRYdw) Includes all test cases except the last, in case it overloaded TIO. Edit: Saved 7 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Explanation:

```
.+
$*i
```

Convert the input number to unary using `i`s.

```
i{64}
s
```

64 items fill one stack.

```
s{27}
c
```

27 stacks fill one chest.

```
(.)\1*
$.&$1
```

Convert any chests, stacks or remaining items to decimal, but leaving the type as a suffix.

```
^$
0i
```

If the input was zero, make the result `0i`.

Comment: Oh my is this really converting to unary then replacing?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I've added an explanation (I didn't have time earlier sorry). (Writing the explanation gave me an opportunity to save a byte too!)

Comment: You can avoid some of that `$.&` duplication like this: https://tio.run/##FYs9DsIwDIX3d46ASpGq2Ens5ARcAiEQYsjCQNmqnj21Lb9veD@/z79/X@M03Z5juSLMHX2TvGPFurHueGNaLneaEZZzIDwCYh8jgsAQ@wTJkAIREKupmho4RhRiUEpminVIPVbP1QqkjRzsSMixiQ1qcmQU3zc7pFoiywE

Comment: @MartinEnder Ah, I was wondering whether it would be worthwhile converting directly to `i` instead of `1`, but I just couldn't see that simplification, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes

```
1728‰`64‰)˜…csiøvyJ¬0Êi?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0NzI4lHDhgQzEyCpeXrOo4ZlycWZh3eUVXodWmNwuCvT/v9/AwA)

**Explanation**

```
1728‰                      # input divmod 1728 (64*27)
     `                     # split as separate with mod result on top of stack
      64‰                  # divmod 64
         )˜                # wrap stack in flattened list
           …csiø           # zip with the string "csi"
                vy         # for each
                  J        # join amount with storage-type
                   ¬0Êi    # if head != 0
                       ?   # print
```

Comment: How does it work in the `0` input case, and why does that also print a trailing newline while other inputs don't?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: If nothing has been printed, 05AB1E implicitly prints the top of the stack at the end of execution (with newline). For-loops breaks lists apart and pushes the elements to the stack, so any item not printed will be added to the stack. At the end of the loop in the `0` case `0i` will be on the top of the stack (`0s` and `0c` will be under it) and will be printed.

Comment: `1728` can be `Ž6Ç` now; and `0Ê` can be `Ā`.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <strike>84</strike> 86 bytes

```
_=>(_/1728>0?_/1728+"c":"")+((_-=_/1728*1728)/64>0?_/64+"s":"")+(_%64>0?_%64+"i":"")
```

Notice the inline subtraction, didn't realize it was possible but `i--` made sense so why not `i-=10`

## Edit:

```
_=>_>0?(_/1728>0?_/1728+"c":"")+((_%=1728)/64>0?_/64+"s":"")+(_%64>0?_%64+"i":""):"0i"
```

for 0 edge case and suggestion.

Comment: +1. And you can change `_-=_/1728*1728` to `_%=1728` to golf a few bytes.

Comment: Also, you forgot about the edge case `0`, which should result in `0i` and is currently outputting nothing. Adding a simply `_>0?...:"0i"` would fix this.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ahh, thank you.

Comment: +1 for `>_>` in the edited one

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```python
lambda n:g(n//1728,"c")+g(n//64%27,"s")+g(n%64,"i")or"0i"
g=lambda n,s:(str(n)+s)*(n>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dasMwDIWv56cwBoPdetQ/iWMH0hfZdpG1TWvYnBL7Inv6VHbpBOcDoXMk3f/ybY5mm4bP7Wf8/T6POPZXFg8H1WknyInwfW1tQ3UnSHr21DaCBMLnhchA0HV4ZUXqWcoLi3yf@I7Fo@RbvqR8GtMlDR9SICWQFsgWGVADakEWJnAA4Ao8uCS4WwVGZUyZ2GKGt7pKV@kLvarUlbC0kd6WqDOVkGrrMg8lkHGt1OWcfNUXQtO84BWHiP@f7dHbfQkxM0IDfj9imghlq5jYyjnfHg)

Comment: In Python 2 this could be shortened to 82 bytes, using simple division (`/`  instead of `//`) and using backtick operator instead of `str(...)`

Answer (score 3):

## C, 85 <del>87</del> <del>105</del> <del>110</del> <del>111</del> <del>112</del> bytes

```
#define a(x,y)x?printf("%d%c",x,y+99):0;
f(z){a(z/1728,0)a(z%1728/64,16)!z+a(z%64,6)}
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##HYxBDsIgFET3nAIxmP9TTFtjUOzCs5BPMSyKRo2pND07grOYzLzFo/2NKOetG32II7cwqy/O18czxLcHIZ0koQprjMFLNzAPCRcLqe1Ph7PqsExZZ6uPqte4SU0l5Whc8@ceHJ9siIBsYcXI3cBeZOPfLNTOYTXWXrMp@QE).

The code even works properly on negative numbers. You may now owe server OP blocks!

Comment: Functions are acceptable as standard on PPCG

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBDsIgFET3nAIxEH76TVNjUNLTkE8xLMRGjak0PTtCZzGZeYtHpztRKUc/hZgm7vSCP1iUml8xfYIW0ksSWGFnLYws6Ayr07kfrucbQl2yrd5ccDBwyF0j9RjYyvcZPX@4mDSwlVUd9yN7k0u7VqDyu7D1VmzNHw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```js
n=>[n+1,1728,64,1].map((v,i,a)=>(v=n%a[--i]/v|0)?v+'csi'[i]:'').join``||'0i'
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>[n+1,1728,64,1].map((v,i,a)=>(v=n%a[--i]/v|0)?v+'csi'[i]:'').join``||'0i'

console.log(f(0)) // -> 0i
console.log(f(1)) // -> 1i
console.log(f(2)) // -> 2i
console.log(f(62)) // -> 62i
console.log(f(63)) // -> 63i
console.log(f(64)) // -> 1s
console.log(f(65)) // -> 1s1i
console.log(f(66)) // -> 1s2i
console.log(f(127)) // -> 1s63i
console.log(f(128)) // -> 2s
console.log(f(129)) // -> 2s1i
console.log(f(200)) // -> 3s8i
console.log(f(512)) // -> 8s
console.log(f(1337)) // -> 20s57i
console.log(f(1664)) // -> 26s
console.log(f(1727)) // -> 26s63i
console.log(f(1728)) // -> 1c
console.log(f(1729)) // -> 1c1i
console.log(f(1791)) // -> 1c63i
console.log(f(1792)) // -> 1c1s
console.log(f(1793)) // -> 1c1s1i
console.log(f(4096)) // -> 2c10s
console.log(f(5183)) // -> 2c26s63i
console.log(f(5184)) // -> 3c
console.log(f(5200)) // -> 3c16i
console.log(f(9999)) // -> 5c21s15i
console.log(f(385026)) // -> 222c22s2i
console.log(f(1000000000)) // -> 578703c19s
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 86 bytes

```
i->i>0?(i/1728>0?i/1728+"c":"")+((i%=1728)/64>0?i/64+"s":"")+((i%=64)>0?i+"i":""):"0i"
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZRfa4MwFMXf9ykugUGC1MZ/UVvafYL1ZY9jD6l1I52NUtPCGP3sLmoHexknRIj3/OAeTy4e9VUv2q62x8PnUDW67@lZG/v9QGSsq8/vuqppN74SvbizsR9Uca@QFWtfvPnH795pZyrakaUNDWaxNVv5xM0yyuPCn@ZDwCq2YkwEnJvHzVgRS5VOskoD1v8RVSrGesDMVFwxadiwnnt1l33je91bXltzoJN3zGd3r2@kxd3uV@/qU9heXNh5yTWW27DiUkzO/9UjoKsYAQkCUgRkCFDoI@IcEgUkSkDEEoWZRSitKEmgVQUT89OUY6TASAmRMsJIjBE0JKksFQy3SDCCosvwLZZ@ASQpMhnDqZS/S9z/HrfhBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 31 bytes

```
ri64md\27md@]"csi"]z{0=},"0i"e|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTzCQ3JcbIPDfFIVYpuThTKbaq2sC2VkfJIFMpteb/f0MDGAAA)

#### Explanation

```
ri                               e# Read an int from input.
  64md                           e# Divmod by 64, gives total #stacks, #items.
      \27md                      e# Divmod total #stacks by 27, gives #chests, #stacks.
           @                     e# Bring #items back to top.
            ]                    e# Wrap in an array: [#chests, #stacks, #items]
             "csi"               e# Push "csi".
                  ]z             e# Zip with the other array.
                    {0=},        e# Filter out subarrays where the first element is 0.
                         "0i"e|  e# Logical or with "0i". An input of 0 gives an empty array
                                 e# from the rest of the program, in that case yield "0i"
                                 e# instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 179 bytes

```
/|/\/\///b/l0|d/11|x/dddd|sbxxxxxxxx/1sb|cbxxxd1/1cb|bxd/1b|d/2|2222/8|222/6|22/4|21/3|81/9|61/7|41/5|bc/gc|cb/c|bs/gs|sb/s|bi/gi|b|/g/0|mc/m|ms/m|mi/0i|m|/si/s|cs/c|ci/c/mcl0sl0i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBDsMwCEM/yaHruu5fdhl0ypCSE5cc/O8ZkfaQjBC2o73j@4k5QbxyAEUrvCDCgSth6PgDCaWt8xKIKXWkUdO9cUtwroUjFTs3wY2n4MlD8OAuuFMN1bICRg3UyHIE1VGdSlQUdkNnjyWO4uxEeJosMmSOfFsr0YrP@QM)

Input is taken in unary `1`s at the end of the program right before the `i`.
Ex:

```
.../si/s|cs/c|ci/c/mcl0sl0<--input here-->i
```

You can also use an `x` in place of 8 `1`s as a side affect of golfing the program. There is a wrapper for easier testing below.

Testing wrapper:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBcpswED1bX7G32NPUixwncTrtsYfec@xFEjJSA4hqRY1n9O/uCuIkkwXE7ujpvd0H1Cpyli4oEBHK8/0rRNuFf5agt6fW95yovgYalOGUApzDCEb14PthTLzCMYRkI@gwLUg72KiSheQs3PibLTK7EM/OE/D9Z6TENJ2FU1QDQ4HSeDxCCtCpF/tKW4iSpeT7Bqwib6MQvxZBgsS4oj8rvKvfgrbHEN@F4XlJeBJbEwiW0BZUmgGWFcJxThdJPjpXQwxNVF1p6BTiS6m5y/a8FT@nb2IlOcRqeg2xEiv/oTVuauxVPN/CySe3zGmcisTKZZZoh5aNrAswxJobZxkTuiFaoqWRrRAS4AeAhHU9uo2Y5uoAaz36tjjORz41@sbQj522sTCxKb1q2/MGQAi3EFYVrN08qBv7Otp6I9J1h7euHoSR2P@N4IG3YpWSWDnnrjPPDoh56usntX9H1XIbYldovsDdvO4PJWX23d09Hzg5bxw0vvxZ0jzR/pEZyq@R0L0Flw6nD1Hcxgtm/M0Xosa2yjVKmSesOTLpKxIl6WxKWUuURmc9MVAzepd3HHgoL3zgFfd5J/EuHyQ@5QeJj3kv8T5rg41hCjRZEzbE5EhZe2x81hkbrHJnsMsdlcVj5XOXkTyDDPEh45G3TVtRW13YtWLaq2ezZf7yHw)

Ungolfed:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VM5DsMwDNv1GUZpmqbPKYTCMRBPWvJ7l5Lzhy4hDNOkzsV@fHz/eu8Q8JzQCxR@TOcFKAUtSyvCamEIaIRKIazGzLSZwDYeWJOxBCkepE3xJq2KF2lRPLP4mAzFxhTYaO4oPlaBR1J4FaWOaKxckHs0Q6NqPqhiypyGuL1GNcyR7SupN05hW5Hzxo3/4/p3IrX/AA)

It does 2 divmods, one to separate into chests, stacks, and items, then again to convert to decimal. I could have it convert input from decimal as well, but I would also have to change all of the symbol names and add additional logic to keep it from breaking, so I'm not going to do that. Besides, I think unary is a recognized standard input for ///.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <sub><s>347 335 283 246 234 202 199 191</s></sub> 189 bytes

```
@set/al=%1,c=%1/1728,l-=c*1728,s=l/64,l-=s*64
@set c=%c%c
@set s=%s%s
@set i=%l%i
@if %c%==0c set c=
@if %s%==0s set s=
@if %i%==0i set i=
@if %c%%s%%i%.==. set i=0i
@echo(%c%%s%%i%
```

Comment: You do know you can use division and modulus in a `set/a` expression, don't you?

Comment: @Neil I know, I'm working as the same way right now

Comment: @Neil I'm just encountering an issue: `if %c%==0 (set c=)else rem` this codes gives me "`(set` is not expected"

Comment: Huh, that should only happen if c is empty...

Comment: @Neil turns out it was an program error. `%c%` was undefined xD

Comment: JFTR my solution (two slightly different variations with the same length) is down to 122 bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60063/discussion-between-stevefest-and-neil).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 71 bytes

```
n=>[n/1728|0,(n/64|0)%27,n%64].map((a,i)=>a?a+'csi'[i]:'').join``||'0i'
```

**Snippet:**

```js
f=
n=>[n/1728|0,(n/64|0)%27,n%64].map((a,i)=>a?a+'csi'[i]:'').join``||'0i'

console.log(f(0)) // 0i
console.log(f(1)) // 1i
console.log(f(2)) // 2i
console.log(f(62)) // 62i
console.log(f(63)) // 63i
console.log(f(64)) // 1s
console.log(f(65)) // 1s1i
console.log(f(66)) // 1s2i
console.log(f(127)) // 1s63i
console.log(f(128)) // 2s
console.log(f(129)) // 2s1i
console.log(f(200)) // 3s8i
console.log(f(512)) // 8s
console.log(f(1337)) // 20s57i
console.log(f(1664)) // 26s
console.log(f(1727)) // 26s63i
console.log(f(1728)) // 1c
console.log(f(1729)) // 1c1i
console.log(f(1791)) // 1c63i
console.log(f(1792)) // 1c1s
console.log(f(1793)) // 1c1s1i
console.log(f(4096)) // 2c10s
console.log(f(5183)) // 2c26s63i
console.log(f(5184)) // 3c
console.log(f(5200)) // 3c16i
console.log(f(9999)) // 5c21s15i
console.log(f(385026)) // 222c22s2i
console.log(f(1000000000)) // 578703c19s
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

I converted Gabor Fekete's comment from above into a working example:

```python
lambda n:g(n/1728,"c")+g(n/64%27,"s")+g(n%64,"i")or"0i"
g=lambda n,s:(`n`+s)*(n>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dasMwDIWv56cwBoO9asw/iWMH0hfZBs26pjNsTolzkT19Jnt0gvOB0NGRbj/r55zMPg2v@9f4/f4x0tRfRXrWnfHAzkweSucabjpg@a/lrgEWmZwXpiIj1@G@CbkXp3Q6ZPko0lHJfb3k9TzmSx5eFBANxABxRRbVoFqUwwmmI3xBQJdCd6vRqK0tE1fM@FJX6StDYdCVphJDGxVcWfW2ErfaGhawgFjfKlPOqXu9ETLNC91oTPT/2Z483JaYVsF4pE9HyjPjYoNJbFLK/Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 76 bytes

```
?dddsf[1728/n99P]sc1728/0<c1728%ddd[64/n115P]si64/0<i[64%n105P]sy64%0<ylf0=y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@JSWlOC3a0NzIQj/P0jIgtjgZzDawAdOqQOloMxP9PENDU6BcJpBpYJMJFFHNMzQAiVQCmQY2lTlpBraV//@bGloYAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 71 bytes

```
V"isc"R#@!%>93*!*,>,>!/!*,>,$_-,>,>,/<$_<&,!?_v@R:>|!?_v@R:>|!?_v@R:>|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/TCmzOFkpSNlBUdXO0lhLUUvHTsdOUR9Mq8Trgng6@jYq8TZqOor28WUOQVZ2NZgM6////1sCAQA)

Not at all golfy, but it works

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 84 bytes

```php
<?=($c=($a=$argn)/1728^0)?$c.c:"",($s=$a/64%27)?$s.s:"",($i=$a%64)||$c+$s<1?$m.i:"";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnBCoQgFEDRfZ8hL0gqy5Acpsw/CeQR2aKScdtvz9oetbibc4MPabTBhwzcbz0MU1pKNmR2IjYFIOXM83gjdfeZW24BBX4ZqwqItJpe5Z0mjSK@upHmveLXBVhCHKWFXWz0hpT@x1mjQ7/c)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 93 bytes

```php
$i-=64*$s=($i-=1728*$c=($i=$argn)/1728^0)/64^0;echo$c?$c.c:"",$s?$s.s:"",$i||$c+$s<1?$i.i:"";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDoMgFAX3PQZ5C7WK2io2RcJNTMyPKWyU@Lde2zUWdzOTCS7E0QYXHpj332rEu1eD0BG@MqorwCZL2A6vTwFKYu4xr1OamrxW3dTohdwGsiBJXyFKsAVLvtEfB@gJHlsLL/2/6RjPdatoJrdc)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 155 bytes

```
A=AppendTo;G={};P=Print;(z=Mod[t=Mod[#,1728],64];If[(x=⌊#/1728⌋)>0,A[G,{x,c}]];If[(y=⌊t/64⌋)>0,A[G,{y,s}]];If[z>0||#==0,A[G,{z,i}]];Row@Flatten@G)&
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, <s>139 134</s> 139 bytes

Input is stored in column *a* of pre-existing table *t*.

```
SELECT IIF(a=0,'0i',REPLACE(IIF(a<1728,'',STR(a/1728)+'c')
                           +IIF(a%1728<64,'',STR(a%1728/64)+'s')
                           +IIF(a%64=0,'',STR(a%64)+'i'),' ',''))FROM t
```

Line breaks for readability, not counted in byte total.
Tested on MS SQL Server 2012.

**EDIT 1:** Changed multiple `REPLACE` to `IIF` to save 5 bytes. Final `REPLACE` still necessary because `STR` annoyingly pads with spaces to 10 chars.

**EDIT 2:** Fixed to follow the rules by using the approved input type for SQL, [values stored in a named table](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172). This cost bytes for the `FROM`, also requires `SELECT` instead of `PRINT`. Recovered 2 bytes by dropping an unnecessary parens.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 113 Bytes

```
param($i)("$(($c=[math]::floor($i/1728)))c","")[!$c]+("$(($s=[math]::floor(($i%1728)/64)))s","")[!$s]+"$($i%64)i"
```

This hits a bunch of powershell's pain points very precisely.

`[math]::Floor` is required for this as PS does Bankers Rounding by default.

the PS Ternary also takes up a load of bytes compared to other languages, to do a simple null coallescence (`$a="This";$a?$a:"That"` or `"This"?:"That"`) we need to do `(($a="This"),"That")[$a-ne$null]`

then we need to use all of these twice, and also add in another set of brackets in some places due to powershell's default operation order.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

```python
lambda n:''.join(`k`+c for k,c in zip([n/1728,n/64%27,n%64],'csi')if k)or'0i'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/dbsMgDIWvx1OgSghQ2cpPQqBS9yJdpaZZo9FsJAq5yPbymUHaLJ3vxsfH9vS9fIxRb/3pbftsv27vLY5HSl8eY4jsOlz3He7HGQ@iwyHinzCxczyoRjsRD7YiuhGR2OoiaJcC5aHHAx9nKgPdlntaujbd0@ksBVICaYFslgFVoBpkoQMZAJfhwSXBXSswKmNyx2YzbGwKXaHP9KpQF0JoJb3No84UwlRdwjyUQMbVUud18q8uCOXX1vzY/7FH9DTNIS5sRwJ@fsUk7QhbRc9Wzvn2Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
d64d1¦27FµTȯ3ịż“csi”$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUwrDgIxEL0M8onOTDttL8AJMGgWAVmHwm0wCK4AFkWyCgVqCQnXoBcpU8HLvCfmfbbrvt/X2qnvaLpynE/3xWeU7@P0fpbhvNptynCZ1dexHG7LWh0IDLUTqIcGqII4GpMxg51DIAaJ2FMtQ7HZsfnRAhQzNeEmAu@yWiFJE4/Q@tkAScGxbbs/fg)

Like Jonathan Allan's essentially-the-same answer before it, this does seem too long.

Even more essentially the same:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
d64d1¦27Fż“csi”ẠƇȯ⁾0i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUw5DgIxDPzQFLaTOMkH@AM1S7FoOyq6hWY/ARIVFRI9QhQgEN8gHwlOwcgzhedYLYdhU2unvuPHSeLsdSvjfrHuy3j4Xo/v6XMp2zv19TmV3XleK4EhUDsH9dAAVbBEYzJmCBECC9g5e6plODY7Nj9agGPmJtLEwVNWKyTXxCO0fjbApUBi2/THDw)