# When life gives you lemons, make lemonade

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

You will be given an input string, anywhere the word `"Lemon"` is found it should be converted to `"Lemonade"` *but* the `a`, `d`, and `e` must be borrowed from somewhere else in the sentence.

---

## Example

Example Input:

> I found a **lemon** when I was a kid

Example Output:

> I foun a **lemonade** whn I was  kid

The **Lemonade** was created by stealing the following superscript letters from the original

> I foun<sup><sup><s>**d**</s></sup></sup> a lemonade wh<sup><sup><s>**e**</s></sup></sup>n I was <sup><sup><s>**a**</s></sup></sup> kid

This is just one possible output example, the "e", "d", and "a", could have been taken from anywhere (*except for from the word `lemon` of course*)

---

## Comments

•If there are not enough `e`, `a`, or `d`s you must output what was do-able with the letters given. For example the input `bdblemon` would output `bblemond`

•The `lemon` text might not always be standalone (space on each side). For example you may have the word `lemons` somewhere in the input and the output should be `lemonades`

•The input may contain any number of `lemon`s, even 0 `lemon`s (in which case the output would be identical to the input)

•You can make your lemonade with uppercase and lowercase letters, for example `leMon` could become `leMonade`, and the `ade` borrowed can be any case (so it could also have become `leMonADe`).
The case of the letter you borrowed must remain what it was when you borrowed it.
(Example input -> output, `he hAD lemOn` -> `h h lemOnADe`)

•Does not have to be a full program, a function alone is fine.

•You may assume input will be only the [CP437 Character Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

---

## Code Golf

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest number of bytes wins!

---

## Pseudo-TestCases

*Note: For any given input there might be **multiple possible outputs** so your program may not output exactly as these test cases do, this is more just so people can understand the logic:

> Input: EpaD leMons
>   Output: p LeMonaDEs
>
> Input: hello world
>   Output: hello world
>
> Input: lemon lemon
>   Output: lemon lemon
>   *(*The `e`, `a`, `d` letters should never be taken from another "Lemon")*
>
> Input: HE HAD lemonade
>   Output: H H lemonADEade
>
> Input: Do you like lemons? You hAd me at lemon!
>   Output: o you lik lemonADes? You h m t lemonade!
>
> Input: AE lemon
>   Output:  lemonAE
>
> Input: 55bad lemon
>   Output: 55b lemonad

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>159</s> <s>157</s> <s>155</s> 162 bytes

*Edit: +7 bytes to "output what was do-able with the letters given" rather than throwing out an error*

---

A recursive function that returns the modified string.

```js
f=(s,a=s.split(/(lemon)/i),n=(a.length-1)*1.5)=>n?f(n,a.map((s,i)=>i&1|!n||(a[i]=s.replace([/a/i,/e/i,/d/i][n%3],c=>(a[--n/3<<1|1]+=c,''))))&&a,n-(n==s)):a.join``
```

#### How it works

The expression `s.split(/(lemon)/i)` splits the input string on `lemon` but preserves the capture groups in the result.

For instance, `"foo lemon bar LEMON baz".split(/(lemon)/i)` will produce the array `[ 'foo ', 'lemon', ' bar ', 'LEMON', ' baz' ]`.

We recursively iterate on this array, extracting the characters `a`, `d` and `e` or their uppercase counterparts from the entries located at an even position, and appending them to the entries located at an odd position.

#### Commented

```js
f = (                                   // given:
  s,                                    //   s = input string or previous value of 'n'
  a = s.split(/(lemon)/i),              //   a = split array, as described above
  n = (a.length - 1) * 1.5              //   n = total number of characters to be found
) =>                                    //
  n ?                                   // if there's still at least one character to find:
    f(                                  //   do a recursive call with:
      n,                                //     1) the current value of 'n'
      a.map((s, i) =>                   //     2) an updated version of 'a', where
        i & 1 | !n || (                 //       for even positions:
          a[i] = s.replace(             //         we look for the next character
            [/a/i, /e/i, /d/i][n % 3],  //           'a', 'e' or 'd' (case insensitive)
            c => (                      //           append it to
              a[--n / 3 << 1 | 1] += c, //           one of the entries at an odd position
              ''                        //           and remove it from the original entry
            )                           //           end of replace() callback
          )                             //         end of replace()
        )                               //       end of position condition
      ) && a,                           //     end of map() -> yield the updated 'a'
      n -                               //     3) the updated value of 'n', skipping the
      (n == s)                          //        current character if not found at all
    )                                   //   end of recursive call
  :                                     // else:
    a.join``                            //   success: join 'a' and return it
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(s,a=s.split(/(lemon)/i),n=(a.length-1)*1.5)=>n?f(n,a.map((s,i)=>i&1|!n||(a[i]=s.replace([/a/i,/e/i,/d/i][n%3],c=>(a[--n/3<<1|1]+=c,''))))&&a,n-(n==s)):a.join``

console.log(f("I found a lemon when I was a kid"))
console.log(f("I found a lemon when I was a kid. I found another lemon when I was older."))
console.log(f("bdblemon"))
console.log(f("he hAD lemOn"))
```

Comment: Throwing a recursion-error doesn't seem to comply to the first rule ("_If there are not enough `e`, `a`, or `d`s you must output what was do-able with the letters given. For example the input `bdblemon` would output `bblemond`_")?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hmm, you're right. I was almost certain that throwing an error was initially allowed. Was it an edit during the grace period of the initial post? (Either that or I dreamed it.) Anyway, I'll try to fix that. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I looked back in the history before making my comment in case it was indeed edited out. You could be right it might have been edited in the first 5 minutes, but no idea how to check that. And no problem, your answer is still pretty impressive, so I'll +1 it in advance. I have no doubt you'll be able to fix the issue (hopefully without causing to much added bytes).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's fixed at the cost of 7 bytes for now.

Comment: @Arnauld Yes sorry I edited that out within the first 2 minutes of the post maybe haha, my apologies

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No worries. At least, I'm not crazy. :-p

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, 130 bytes

```
LqY5m*{"lemon"_eu}%3/:z{~?}f%{_@\/_:,[{1$+}*]);@f{[\]}@+\1a*}/\{1
=}$0f=\1$,{"ade"{__C#)\Ceu#)|(\0+We\)@_N=@+N\t\}fC}fN0a/L*1a/\.{}
```

This is split across two lines for clarity; the newline is not counted.

#### Pseudocode:

```python3
FLAG_1 = object()
FLAG_2 = object()
lemon_instances = [] # CJam: L
input_chars = list(all_input()) # CJam: q
lemons = [
    "LEMON", "LEMOn", "LEMoN", "LEMon", "LEmON", "LEmOn", "LEmoN", "LEmon",
    "LeMON", "LeMOn", "LeMoN", "LeMon", "LemON", "LemOn", "LemoN", "Lemon",
    "lEMON", "lEMOn", "lEMoN", "lEMon", "lEmON", "lEmOn", "lEmoN", "lEmon",
    "leMON", "leMOn", "leMoN", "leMon", "lemON", "lemOn", "lemoN", "lemon"
] # CJam: Y5m*{"lemon"_eu}%3/:z{~?}f%
for i in lemons: # CJam: { ... }/
    temp = input_chars.split(i) # CJam: _@\/
    lengths = temp.map(len) # CJam: _:,
    # Here, accum turns an array like [1,2,3] into [1,3,6].
    indices = accum(lengths) # CJam: [{1$+}*]
    indices.pop() # CJam: );
    temp2 = zip(temp, indices) # CJam: @f{[\]}
    lemon_instances = temp2 + lemon_instances # CJam: @+
    input_chars = join_array(temp, FLAG_1) # CJam: 1a*
lemon_instances.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # CJam: {1=}$
lemon_instances = [i[0] for i in lemon_instances] # CJam: 0f=
for i in range(len(lemon_instances)): # CJam: \1$,{...}fN
    for c in "ade": # CJam: "ade"{...}fC
        # list_index returns -1 if not found
        lower = list_index(input_chars, c)+1 # CJam: __C#)
        upper = list_index(input_chars, upper(c))+1 # CJam: \Ceu#)
        char_index = (lower or upper) - 1 # CJam: |(
        input_chars.append(FLAG_2) # CJam: \0+
        # -1 refers to the last element in the list
        swap_list_elements(input_chars, char_index, -1) # CJam: e\
        extracted = input_chars.pop() # CJam: )
        lemon_instances[i] += extracted # CJam: @_N=@+N\t\
remove_all(input_chars, FLAG_2) # CJam: 0a/L*
temp1 = input_chars.split(FLAG_1) # CJam: 1a/
# interleave([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"]) gives [1, "a", 2, "b", 3]
temp2 = interleave(temp1, lemon_instances) # CJam: \.{}
print("".join(temp2))
```

Comment: I'm saddened this doesn't have more upvotes, great answer imo

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 303 bytes

```
i+`(?<!lemon)(a)(.*)(lemon)(?!a)
$2$3$1
i+`(lemon)(?!a)(.*)(?<!lemon)(a)
$1$3$2
i+(?<!lemona?)(d)(.*)(lemona?)(?![ad])
$2$3$1
i+`(lemona?)(?![ad])(.*)(?<!lemona?)(d)
$1$3$2
i+(?<!lemona?d?)(e)(?!(?<=le)mon)(.*)(lemona?d?)(?![ade])
$2$3$1
i+`(lemona?d?)(?![ade])(.*)(?<!lemona?d?)(e)(?!(?<=le)mon)
$1$3$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#bY7NCsIwEITveYotREhUhNarkqP0CTyI0IVsNfTvEGrx6WuSVona48zOfLMrcSpGsymEOiQ1NV0rBUqxW0sxK5WgZDzje54yn4vsEIt7jKcul7ncx0YlhY6AXqvkgvr6T41uX@iJsQjX7kS@5bxjTTI8Eo3pN5IW9@Lzz@QSeX5hHM93aqE2JcHNPMjCs@sh9OwWGqxoEg7Lcii7vtWAkwWDb@YwoHVWZfQL)

Surely I'm doing something wrong here.